# Get current Word document's save directory

Tags: vba, ms-word, save

I have a Word document that is already saved and I need to get its existing save directory and/or full file path (i.e. C:\Users\Public\Documents\testDoc.docx).

How can this be acquired from a macro/VBA?

Comment: `x = documents(1).path & documents(1).name` should get you started (x becomes both the path and the file name.)

Comment: @tbur, you will need `& "\" &` between `.path` and `.name` properties...

Comment: @KazJaw, Oh, it's so much worse than just the missing backslash. Yes, I missed that (how I'll never know). But **shahkalpesh**'s Answer using `Activedocument.FullName` is superior in every way.

Comment: FullName is nice, but if the document is on OneDrive, it yields the network name (https://...). But how to get the local filename?

Comment: @PeterL, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) to convert the Url to the local filename.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ActiveDocument.FullName
```

The above gives the full path to the document, including the file name.

```
ActiveDocument.Path
```

The above gives the directory where your document is saved.

```
ActiveDocument.Name
```

The above gives the name of the document, without path information.