# Excel's fullname property with OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

If I want to use the open Workbook object to get the fullname of an Excel file after saving it, but that file has been synchronized to OneDrive, I get a "https" address instead of a local one, which other programs cannot interpret.
How do I get the local filename of a file like this?

Example:
Save a file to "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Company\Documents".
OneDrive does its synchronization.
Querying Workbook.FullName now shows as "https://..."

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Universal Solution & Meta-Analysis of All Solutions

**TLDR**:

- For the solution, skip to the section **The Solutions**
- For the meta-analysis, skip to the section **Testing and comparison of solutions**

### Background

@Cristian Buse and I worked extensively on this problem after testing all other solutions available online and finding none of them universally accurate.

In the end, both of us created independent solutions:

- @Cristian Buse developed his solution as part of one of his excellent VBA Libraries, to be specific, the Library `VBA-FileTools`. This library also provides a bunch of other very useful functionalities.
- My solution comes in the form of a standalone function without any dependencies. This is useful if this problem occurs in a small project where no additional functionality is required. Because implementing the desired universal functionality is complex, it is very long and convoluted for a single procedure.

---

## The Solutions

**NOTES:**

- Should you encounter any bugs with our solutions, **please report them here or on GitHub!** In that case, I recommend you use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457) in the meantime, as it is the next most accurate solution available.

### Solution 1 - Library

Import this library: [VBA-FileTools](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools)
 from GitHub into your project. Getting the local name of your workbook is then as easy as:

```vb
GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
```

> <sup>**Notes:**
>
> Full Mac support was added to this solution on Apr 5, 2023.
>
> Support for OneDrive version 23.184.0903.0001 was added to this solution on Sep 25, 2023.</sup>

### Solution 2 - Standalone Function

Copy [this function](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d), from GitHub Gist into any standard code module.

Getting the local name of your workbook now works in the same way as with Solution 1:

```vb
GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
```

> <sup>**Notes:**
>
> Partial Mac support was added to this solution on Dec 20, 2022, and full support on Mar 20, 2023.
>
> Support for OneDrive version 23.184.0903.0001 was added to this solution on Oct 2, 2023.
>
> This function also offers some optional parameters, but they should almost never be needed. (See Gist for more information)</sup>

You can also copy the shortened function (because of StackOverflows 30 000 character answer length limit) directly from here:

```vb
'Function for converting a OneDrive URL to the corresponding local path
'Algorithmically shortened code from here: 
'https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d
'Author: Guido Witt-Dörring
Public Function GetLocalPath$(ByVal path$, Optional ByVal returnAll As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal preferredMountPointOwner$ = "", Optional ByVal rebuildCache As Boolean = False)
#If Mac Then
Const dr& = 70, ck$ = ".849C9593-D756-4E56-8D6E-42412F2A707B", ew As Boolean = True, ab$ = "/"
#Else
Const ab$ = "\", ew As Boolean = False
#End If
Const ax$ = "GetLocalPath", ex& = 53, fr& = 7, fs& = 457, ey& = 325
Static ac As Collection, ez As Date
If Not Left$(path, 8) = "https://" Then GetLocalPath = path: Exit Function
Dim r$, i$, b$, d
Dim ds$: ds = LCase$(preferredMountPointOwner)
If Not ac Is Nothing And Not rebuildCache Then
Dim bp As Collection: Set bp = New Collection
For Each d In ac
i = d(0): r = d(1)
If InStr(1, path, r, 1) = 1 Then bp.Add Key:=d(2), Item:=Replace(Replace(path, r, i, , 1), "/", ab)
Next d
If bp.count > 0 Then
If returnAll Then
For Each d In bp: b = b & "//" & d: Next d
GetLocalPath = Mid$(b, 3): Exit Function
End If
On Error Resume Next: GetLocalPath = bp(ds): On Error GoTo 0
If GetLocalPath <> "" Then Exit Function
GetLocalPath = bp(1): Exit Function
End If
GetLocalPath = path
End If
Dim bg As Collection: Set bg = New Collection
Dim ay, du$
#If Mac Then
Dim cl$, dv As Boolean
b = Environ("HOME")
du = b & "/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/CLP/"
b = Left$(b, InStrRev(b, "/Library/Containers/", , 0))
bg.Add b & "Library/Containers/com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac/Data/Library/Application Support/OneDrive/settings/"
bg.Add b & "Library/Application Support/OneDrive/settings/"
cl = b & "Library/CloudStorage/"
#Else
bg.Add Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\"
du = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Office\CLP\"
#End If
Dim a&
#If Mac Then
Dim az() As Variant: ReDim az(1 To bg.count * 11 + 1)
For Each ay In bg
For a = a + 1 To a + 9
az(a) = ay & "Business" & a Mod 11
Next a
az(a) = ay: a = a + 1
az(a) = ay & "Personal"
Next ay
az(a + 1) = cl
Dim dw As Boolean
dw = getsetting("GetLocalPath", "AccessRequestInfoMsg", "Displayed", "False") = "True"
If Not dw Then MsgBox "The current VBA Project requires access to the OneDrive settings files to translate a OneDrive URL to the local path of the locally synchronized file/folder on your Mac. Because these files are located outside of Excels sandbox, file-access must be granted explicitly. Please approve the access requests following this message.", vbInformation
If Not GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(az) Then Err.Raise dr, ax
#End If
Dim db As Collection: Set db = New Collection
For Each ay In bg
Dim h$: h = Dir(ay, 16)
Do Until h = ""
If h = "Personal" Or h Like "Business#" Then db.Add Item:=ay & h & ab
h = Dir(, 16)
Loop
Next ay
If Not ac Is Nothing Or ew Then
Dim bf As Collection: Set bf = New Collection
Dim g
For Each g In db
Dim t$: t = IIf(g Like "*" & ab & "Personal" & ab, "????????????*", "????????-????-????-????-????????????")
Dim p$: p = Dir(g, vbNormal)
Do Until p = ""
If p Like t & ".ini" Or p Like t & ".dat" Or p Like "ClientPolicy*.ini" Or StrComp(p, "GroupFolders.ini", 1) = 0 Or StrComp(p, "global.ini", 1) = 0 Or StrComp(p, "SyncEngineDatabase.db", 1) = 0 Then bf.Add Item:=g & p
p = Dir
Loop
Next g
End If
If Not ac Is Nothing And Not rebuildCache Then
Dim au
For Each au In bf
If FileDateTime(au) > ez Then rebuildCache = True: Exit For
Next au
If Not rebuildCache Then Exit Function
End If
Dim f&, am$, e() As Byte, j&, q&, bs&, av() As Byte, cn$, n() As Byte, ao$, ak() As Byte, ba() As Byte, bt$, aw&, y&, dz&, ea&
ez = Now()
#If Mac Then
Dim z As Collection: Set z = New Collection
h = Dir(cl, 16)
Do Until h = ""
If h Like "OneDrive*" Then
dv = True
g = cl & h & ab
au = cl & h & ab & ck
z.Add Item:=g
bf.Add Item:=g
bf.Add Item:=au
End If
h = Dir(, 16)
Loop
If ac Is Nothing Then
Dim dc
If bf.count > 0 Then
ReDim dc(1 To bf.count)
For a = 1 To UBound(dc): dc(a) = bf(a): Next a
If Not GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(dc) Then Err.Raise dr, ax
End If
End If
If dv Then
For a = z.count To 1 Step -1
Dim bu&: bu = 0
On Error Resume Next
bu = GetAttr(z(a) & ck)
Dim bv As Boolean: bv = False
If Err.Number = 0 Then bv = Not CBool(bu And 16)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not bv Then
h = Dir(z(a), 16)
Do Until h = ""
If Not h Like ".Trash*" And h <> "Icon" Then
z.Add z(a) & h & ab
z.Add z(a) & h & ab & ck, z(a) & h & ab
End If
h = Dir(, 16)
Loop
z.Remove a
End If
Next a
If z.count > 0 Then
ReDim az(1 To z.count)
For a = 1 To z.count: az(a) = z(a): Next a
If Not GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(az) Then Err.Raise dr, ax
End If
On Error Resume Next
For a = z.count To 1 Step -1
z.Remove z(a)
Next a
On Error GoTo 0
Dim eb As Collection
Set eb = New Collection
For Each g In z
bu = 0
On Error Resume Next
bu = GetAttr(g & ck)
bv = False
If Err.Number = 0 Then bv = Not CBool(bu And 16)
On Error GoTo 0
If bv Then
f = FreeFile(): b = "": au = g & ck
Dim ec As Boolean: ec = False
On Error GoTo ReadFailed
Open au For Binary Access Read As #f
ReDim e(0 To LOF(f)): Get f, , e: b = e
ec = True
ReadFailed: On Error GoTo -1
Close #f: f = 0
On Error GoTo 0
If ec Then
av = b
If LenB(b) > 0 Then
ReDim n(0 To LenB(b) * 2 - 1): q = 0
For j = LBound(av) To UBound(av)
n(q) = av(j): q = q + 2
Next j
b = n
Else: b = ""
End If
Else
au = MacScript("return path to startup disk as string") & Replace(Mid$(au, 2), ab, ":")
b = MacScript("return read file """ & au & """ as string")
End If
If InStr(1, b, """guid"" : """, 0) Then
b = Split(b, """guid"" : """)(1)
am = Left$(b, InStr(1, b, """", 0) - 1)
eb.Add Key:=am, Item:=VBA.Array(am, Left$(g, Len(g) - 1))
Else
Debug.Print "Warning, empty syncIDFile encountered!"
End If
End If
Next g
End If
If Not dw Then savesetting "GetLocalPath", "AccessRequestInfoMsg", "Displayed", "True"
#End If
Dim c, w$(), s&, co$, bk$, dd$, cp$, bl$, aa$, al$, at$, bz$, fx$, ca As Boolean, cb$, cc$, de$, fc$, fd$, ag$, fe$
Dim ff$: ff = ChrB$(2)
Dim ed As String * 4: MidB$(ed, 1) = ChrB$(1)
Dim ee$: ee = ChrB$(0)
#If Mac Then
Const ef$ = vbNullChar & vbNullChar
#Else
Const ef$ = vbNullChar
#End If
Dim cq As Collection, fi As Date
Set cq = New Collection
Set ac = New Collection
For Each g In db
h = Mid$(g, InStrRev(g, ab, Len(g) - 1, 0) + 1)
h = Left$(h, Len(h) - 1)
If Dir(g & "global.ini", vbNormal) = "" Then GoTo NextFolder
f = FreeFile()
Open g & "global.ini" For Binary Access Read As #f
ReDim e(0 To LOF(f)): Get f, , e
Close #f: f = 0
#If Mac Then
bt = e: GoSub DecodeUTF8
e = ao
#End If
For Each c In Split(e, vbNewLine)
If c Like "cid = *" Then t = Mid$(c, 7): Exit For
Next c
If t = "" Then GoTo NextFolder
If (Dir(g & t & ".ini") = "" Or (Dir(g & "SyncEngineDatabase.db") = "" And Dir(g & t & ".dat") = "")) Then GoTo NextFolder
If h Like "Business#" Then
bz = Replace(Space$(32), " ", "[a-f0-9]") & "*"
ElseIf h = "Personal" Then
bz = Replace(Space$(12), " ", "[A-F0-9]") & "*!###*"
End If
p = Dir(du, vbNormal)
Do Until p = ""
a = InStrRev(p, t, , 1)
If a > 1 And t <> "" Then bl = LCase$(Left$(p, a - 2)): Exit Do
p = Dir
Loop
#If Mac Then
On Error Resume Next
fi = cq(h)
ca = (Err.Number = 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If ca Then
If FileDateTime(g & t & ".ini") < fi Then
GoTo NextFolder
Else
For a = ac.count To 1 Step -1
If ac(a)(5) = h Then
ac.Remove a
End If
Next a
cq.Remove h
cq.Add Key:=h, Item:=FileDateTime(g & t & ".ini")
End If
Else
cq.Add Key:=h, Item:=FileDateTime(g & t & ".ini")
End If
#End If
Dim bb As Collection: Set bb = New Collection
p = Dir(g, vbNormal)
Do Until p = ""
If p Like "ClientPolicy*.ini" Then
f = FreeFile()
Open g & p For Binary Access Read As #f
ReDim e(0 To LOF(f)): Get f, , e
Close #f: f = 0
#If Mac Then
bt = e: GoSub DecodeUTF8
e = ao
#End If
bb.Add Key:=p, Item:=New Collection
For Each c In Split(e, vbNewLine)
If InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) Then
bk = Left$(c, InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) - 1)
b = Mid$(c, InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) + 3)
Select Case bk
Case "DavUrlNamespace"
bb(p).Add Key:=bk, Item:=b
Case "SiteID", "IrmLibraryId", "WebID"
b = Replace(LCase$(b), "-", "")
If Len(b) > 3 Then b = Mid$(b, 2, Len(b) - 2)
bb(p).Add Key:=bk, Item:=b
End Select
End If
Next c
End If
p = Dir
Loop
Dim x As Collection: Set x = Nothing
If Dir(g & t & ".dat") = "" Then GoTo Continue
Const fz& = 1000
Const cs& = 255
Dim bc&: bc = -1
Try: On Error GoTo Catch
Set x = New Collection
Dim ct&: ct = 1
Dim cu As Date: cu = FileDateTime(g & t & ".dat")
a = 0
Do
If FileDateTime(g & t & ".dat") > cu Then GoTo Try
f = FreeFile
Open g & t & ".dat" For Binary Access Read As #f
Dim dg&: dg = LOF(f)
If bc = -1 Then bc = dg
ReDim e(0 To bc + fz)
Get f, ct, e: b = e
Dim cv&: cv = LenB(b)
Close #f: f = 0
ct = ct + bc
For d = 16 To 8 Step -8
a = InStrB(d + 1, b, ed, 0)
Do While a > d And a < cv - 168
If StrComp(MidB$(b, a - d, 1), ff, 0) = 0 Then
a = a + 8: s = InStrB(a, b, ee, 0) - a
If s < 0 Then s = 0
If s > 39 Then s = 39
#If Mac Then
cn = MidB$(b, a, s)
GoSub DecodeANSI: al = ao
#Else
al = StrConv(MidB$(b, a, s), 64)
#End If
a = a + 39: s = InStrB(a, b, ee, 0) - a
If s < 0 Then s = 0
If s > 39 Then s = 39
#If Mac Then
cn = MidB$(b, a, s)
GoSub DecodeANSI: aa = ao
#Else
aa = StrConv(MidB$(b, a, s), 64)
#End If
a = a + 121
s = InStr(-Int(-(a - 1) / 2) + 1, b, ef, 0) * 2 - a - 1
If s > cs * 2 Then s = cs * 2
If s < 0 Then s = 0
If al Like bz And aa Like bz Then
#If Mac Then
Do While s Mod 4 > 0
If s > cs * 4 Then Exit Do
s = InStr(-Int(-(a + s) / 2) + 1, b, ef, 0) * 2 - a - 1
Loop
If s > cs * 4 Then s = cs * 4
ak = MidB$(b, a, s)
ReDim n(LBound(ak) To UBound(ak))
j = LBound(ak): q = LBound(ak)
Do While j < UBound(ak)
If ak(j + 2) + ak(j + 3) = 0 Then
n(q) = ak(j)
n(q + 1) = ak(j + 1)
q = q + 2
Else
If ak(j + 3) <> 0 Then Err.Raise ey, ax
y = ak(j + 2) * &H10000 + ak(j + 1) * &H100& + ak(j)
bs = y - &H10000
ea = &HD800& Or (bs \ &H400&)
dz = &HDC00& Or (bs And &H3FF)
n(q) = ea And &HFF&
n(q + 1) = ea \ &H100&
n(q + 2) = dz And &HFF&
n(q + 3) = dz \ &H100&
q = q + 4
End If
j = j + 4
Loop
If q > LBound(n) Then
ReDim Preserve n(LBound(n) To q - 1)
at = n
Else: at = ""
End If
#Else
at = MidB$(b, a, s)
#End If
x.Add VBA.Array(aa, at), al
End If
End If
a = InStrB(a + 1, b, ed, 0)
Loop
If x.count > 0 Then Exit For
Next d
Loop Until ct >= dg Or bc >= dg
GoTo Continue
Catch:
Select Case Err.Number
Case fs
x.Remove al
Resume
Case Is <> fr: Err.Raise Err, ax
End Select
If bc > &HFFFFF Then bc = bc / 2: Resume Try
Err.Raise Err, ax
Continue:
On Error GoTo 0
If Not x Is Nothing Then GoTo SkipDbFile
f = FreeFile()
Open g & "SyncEngineDatabase.db" For Binary Access Read As #f
cv = LOF(f)
If cv = 0 Then GoTo CloseFile
Dim eg$: eg = ChrW$(&H808)
Const gd& = 8, ge& = -3, fl As Byte = 9, fm& = 6, fn& = &H16, gf& = &H15, ce& = -16, cf& = -15, eh& = &H100000
Dim bm&, cg&, bd&, ah(1 To 4) As Byte, an$, dk$, ei&, ej&, ek&, dl&, el As Byte, em As Byte, en As Boolean, eo&
cu = 0
ReDim e(1 To eh)
Do
a = 0
If FileDateTime(g & "SyncEngineDatabase.db") > cu Then
Set x = New Collection
Dim dm As Collection: Set dm = New Collection
cu = FileDateTime(g & "SyncEngineDatabase.db")
bm = 1
an = ""
End If
If LenB(an) > 0 Then
at = MidB$(b, ei, ej)
End If
Get f, bm, e
b = e
a = InStrB(1 - ce, b, eg, 0)
dl = 0
Do While a > 0
If a + ce - 2 > dl And LenB(an) > 0 Then
If dl > 0 Then
at = MidB$(b, ei, ej)
End If
bt = at: GoSub DecodeUTF8
at = ao
On Error Resume Next
x.Add VBA.Array(dk, at), an
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
If dm(an) < em Then
If x(an)(1) <> at Or x(an)(0) <> dk Then
x.Remove an
dm.Remove an
x.Add VBA.Array(dk, at), an
End If
End If
End If
dm.Add em, an
On Error GoTo 0
an = ""
End If
If e(a + ge) <> gd Then GoTo NextSig
en = True
eo = 0
If e(a + cf) = gf Then
j = a + cf
ElseIf e(a + ce) = fn Then
j = a + ce
en = False
ElseIf e(a + cf) <= fl Then
j = a + cf
ElseIf e(a + cf) = fn Then
j = a + cf
eo = 1
Else
GoTo NextSig
End If
el = e(j)
cg = fm
For q = 1 To 4
If q = 1 And el <= fl Then
ah(q) = e(j + 2)
Else
ah(q) = e(j + q)
End If
If ah(q) < 37 Or ah(q) Mod 2 = 0 Then GoTo NextSig
ah(q) = (ah(q) - 13) / 2
cg = cg + ah(q)
Next q
If en Then
bd = e(j + 5)
If bd < 15 Or bd Mod 2 = 0 Then GoTo NextSig
bd = (bd - 13) / 2
Else
bd = (e(j + 5) - 128) * 64 + (e(j + 6) - 13) / 2
If bd < 1 Or e(j + 6) Mod 2 = 0 Then GoTo NextSig
End If
cg = cg + bd
ek = a + cg - 1
If ek > eh Then
a = a - 1
Exit Do
End If
j = a + fm + eo
#If Mac Then
cn = MidB$(b, j, ah(1))
GoSub DecodeANSI: al = ao
#Else
al = StrConv(MidB$(b, j, ah(1)), 64)
#End If
j = j + ah(1)
aa = StrConv(MidB$(b, j, ah(2)), 64)
#If Mac Then
cn = MidB$(b, j, ah(2))
GoSub DecodeANSI: aa = ao
#Else
aa = StrConv(MidB$(b, j, ah(2)), 64)
#End If
If al Like bz And aa Like bz Then
ei = j + ah(2) + ah(3) + ah(4)
ej = bd
an = Left$(al, 32)
dk = Left$(aa, 32)
em = el
dl = ek
End If
NextSig:
a = InStrB(a + 1, b, eg, 0)
Loop
If a = 0 Then
bm = bm + eh + ce
Else
bm = bm + a + ce
End If
Loop Until bm > cv
CloseFile:
Close #f
SkipDbFile:
f = FreeFile()
Open g & t & ".ini" For Binary Access Read As #f
ReDim e(0 To LOF(f)): Get f, , e
Close #f: f = 0
#If Mac Then
bt = e: GoSub DecodeUTF8:
e = ao
#End If
Dim ep As Collection: Set ep = New Collection
Dim eq
eq = VBA.Array("libraryScope", "libraryFolder", "AddedScope")
Dim dn As Collection: Set dn = New Collection
For Each d In eq
dn.Add New Collection, CStr(d)
Next d
For Each c In Split(e, vbNewLine)
If InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) = 0 Then Exit For
bk = Left$(c, InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) - 1)
Select Case bk: Case "libraryScope", "libraryFolder", "AddedScope"
dn(bk).Add c, Split(c, " ", 4, 0)(2)
End Select
Next c
For Each d In eq
Dim dp As Collection: Set dp = dn(d)
a = 0
Do Until dp.count = 0
On Error Resume Next
c = "": c = dp(CStr(a))
On Error GoTo 0
If c <> "" Then
ep.Add c
dp.Remove CStr(a)
End If
a = a + 1
Loop
Next d
If h Like "Business#" Then
Dim er As Collection: Set er = New Collection
dd = ""
For Each c In ep
r = "": i = "": w = Split(c, """")
Select Case Left$(c, InStr(1, c, " = ", 0) - 1)
Case "libraryScope"
i = w(9)
ag = i: am = Split(w(10), " ")(2)
co = Split(c, " ")(2)
fx = w(3): w = Split(w(8), " ")
cb = w(1): de = w(2): cc = w(3)
If Split(c, " ", 4, 0)(2) = "0" Then
dd = i: p = "ClientPolicy.ini"
fd = am: fe = ag
Else: p = "ClientPolicy_" & cc & cb & ".ini"
End If
On Error Resume Next
r = bb(p)("DavUrlNamespace")
On Error GoTo 0
If r = "" Then
For Each d In bb
If d("SiteID") = cb And d("WebID") = de And d("IrmLibraryId") = cc Then
r = d("DavUrlNamespace"): Exit For
End If
Next d
End If
If r = "" Then Err.Raise ex, ax
er.Add VBA.Array(co, r), co
If Not i = "" Then ac.Add VBA.Array(i, r, bl, am, ag, h), Key:=i
Case "libraryFolder"
co = Split(c, " ")(3)
i = w(1): ag = i
am = Split(w(4), " ")(1)
b = "": aa = Left$(Split(c, " ")(4), 32)
Do
On Error Resume Next: x aa
ca = (Err.Number = 0): On Error GoTo 0
If Not ca Then Exit Do
b = x(aa)(1) & "/" & b
aa = x(aa)(0)
Loop
r = er(co)(1) & b
ac.Add VBA.Array(i, r, bl, am, ag, h), i
Case "AddedScope"
If dd = "" Then Err.Raise ey, ax
cp = w(5): If cp = " " Then cp = ""
w = Split(w(4), " "): cb = w(1)
de = w(2): cc = w(3): fc = w(4)
p = "ClientPolicy_" & cc & cb & fc & ".ini"
On Error Resume Next
r = bb(p)("DavUrlNamespace") & cp
On Error GoTo 0
If r = "" Then
For Each d In bb
If d("SiteID") = cb And d("WebID") = de And d("IrmLibraryId") = cc Then
r = d("DavUrlNamespace") & cp
Exit For
End If
Next d
End If
If r = "" Then Err.Raise ex, ax
b = "": aa = Left$(Split(c, " ")(3), 32)
Do
On Error Resume Next: x aa
ca = (Err.Number = 0): On Error GoTo 0
If Not ca Then Exit Do
b = x(aa)(1) & ab & b
aa = x(aa)(0)
Loop
i = dd & ab & b
ac.Add VBA.Array(i, r, bl, fd, fe, h), i
Case Else: Exit For
End Select
Next c
ElseIf h = "Personal" Then
For Each c In Split(e, vbNewLine)
If c Like "library = *" Then
w = Split(c, """"): i = w(3)
ag = i: am = Split(w(4), " ")(2)
Exit For
End If
Next c
On Error Resume Next
r = bb("ClientPolicy.ini")("DavUrlNamespace")
On Error GoTo 0
If i = "" Or r = "" Or t = "" Then GoTo NextFolder
ac.Add VBA.Array(i, r & "/" & t, bl, am, ag, h), Key:=i
If Dir(g & "GroupFolders.ini") = "" Then GoTo NextFolder
t = "": f = FreeFile()
Open g & "GroupFolders.ini" For Binary Access Read As #f
ReDim e(0 To LOF(f)): Get f, , e
Close #f: f = 0
#If Mac Then
bt = e: GoSub DecodeUTF8
e = ao
#End If
For Each c In Split(e, vbNewLine)
If c Like "*_BaseUri = *" And t = "" Then
t = LCase$(Mid$(c, InStrRev(c, "/", , 0) + 1, InStrRev(c, "!", , 0) - InStrRev(c, "/", , 0) - 1))
al = Left$(c, InStr(1, c, "_", 0) - 1)
ElseIf t <> "" Then
ac.Add VBA.Array(i & ab & x(al)(1), r & "/" & t & "/" & Mid$(c, Len(al) + 9), bl, am, ag, h), Key:=i & ab & x(al)(1)
t = "": al = ""
End If
Next c
End If
NextFolder:
t = "": b = "": bl = ""
Next g
Dim ch As Collection: Set ch = New Collection
For Each d In ac
i = d(0): r = d(1): ag = d(4)
If Right$(r, 1) = "/" Then r = Left$(r, Len(r) - 1)
If Right$(i, 1) = ab Then i = Left$(i, Len(i) - 1)
If Right$(ag, 1) = ab Then ag = Left$(ag, Len(ag) - 1)
ch.Add VBA.Array(i, r, d(2), d(3), ag), i
Next d
Set ac = ch
#If Mac Then
If dv Then
Set ch = New Collection
For Each d In ac
i = d(0): am = d(3): ag = d(4)
i = Replace(i, ag, eb(am)(1), , 1)
ch.Add VBA.Array(i, d(1), d(2)), i
Next d
Set ac = ch
End If
#End If
GetLocalPath = GetLocalPath(path, returnAll, ds, False): Exit Function
Exit Function
DecodeUTF8:
Const ci As Boolean = False
Dim u&, o&, bn&
Static cj(0 To 255) As Byte
Static fp&(2 To 4)
Static dq&(2 To 4)
If cj(0) = 0 Then
For u = &H0& To &H7F&: cj(u) = 1: Next u
For u = &HC2& To &HDF&: cj(u) = 2: Next u
For u = &HE0& To &HEF&: cj(u) = 3: Next u
For u = &HF0& To &HF4&: cj(u) = 4: Next u
For u = 2 To 4: fp(u) = (2 ^ (7 - u) - 1): Next u
dq(2) = &H80&: dq(3) = &H800&: dq(4) = &H10000
End If
Dim es As Byte
ba = bt
ReDim n(0 To (UBound(ba) - LBound(ba) + 1) * 2)
o = 0
u = LBound(ba)
Do While u <= UBound(ba)
y = ba(u)
aw = cj(y)
If aw = 0 Then
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
GoTo insertErrChar
ElseIf aw = 1 Then
n(o) = y
o = o + 2
ElseIf u + aw - 1 > UBound(ba) Then
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
GoTo insertErrChar
Else
y = ba(u) And fp(aw)
For bn = 1 To aw - 1
es = ba(u + bn)
If (es And &HC0&) = &H80& Then
y = (y * &H40&) + (es And &H3F)
Else
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
GoTo insertErrChar
End If
Next bn
If y < dq(aw) Then
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
GoTo insertErrChar
ElseIf y < &HD800& Then
n(o) = CByte(y And &HFF&)
n(o + 1) = CByte(y \ &H100&)
o = o + 2
ElseIf y < &HE000& Then
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
GoTo insertErrChar
ElseIf y < &H10000 Then
If y = &HFEFF& Then GoTo nextCp
n(o) = y And &HFF&
n(o + 1) = y \ &H100&
o = o + 2
ElseIf y < &H110000 Then
bs = y - &H10000
Dim et&: et = &HDC00& Or (bs And &H3FF)
Dim eu&: eu = &HD800& Or (bs \ &H400&)
n(o) = eu And &HFF&
n(o + 1) = eu \ &H100&
n(o + 2) = et And &HFF&
n(o + 3) = et \ &H100&
o = o + 4
Else
If ci Then Err.Raise 5
insertErrChar: n(o) = &HFD
n(o + 1) = &HFF
o = o + 2
If aw = 0 Then aw = 1
End If
End If
nextCp: u = u + aw
Loop
ao = MidB$(n, 1, o)
Return
DecodeANSI:
av = cn
o = UBound(av) - LBound(av) + 1
If o > 0 Then
ReDim n(0 To o * 2 - 1): bn = 0
For o = LBound(av) To UBound(av)
n(bn) = av(o): bn = bn + 2
Next o
ao = n
Else
ao = ""
End If
Return
End Function
```

---

## How Do the Solutions Work?

Both solutions get all of the required information for translating the OneDrive URL to a local path from the OneDrive settings files inside of the directory `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\...`.

The following files may be read:

(Wildcards: `*` - zero or more characters; `?` - one character)

```
????????????????.dat
????????????????.ini
global.ini
GroupFolders.ini
????????-????-????-????-????????????.dat
????????-????-????-????-????????????.ini
ClientPolicy*.ini
SyncEngineDatabase.db
```

Data from all of these files is used, to create a "dictionary" of all the local mount points on your pc, and their corresponding OneDrive URL-root. For example, for your personal OneDrive, such a local mount point could look like this:
`C:\Users\Username\OneDrive`, and the corresponding URL-root could look like this: `https://d.docs.live.net/f9d8c1184686d493`.

For more information on how exactly the dictionary is built and used, please refer to the extensive comments above the code in [the Gist](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d) of the standalone function and the resources linked there.

---

## Testing and Comparison of Solutions

I conducted extensive testing of all solutions I could find online. A selection of these tests will be presented here.

This is a list of some of the tested solutions:

| Nr. | Author | Solution | Tests passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Koen Rijnsent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552016) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/71753164/12287457 | 0/46 |
| 2 | [Cooz2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/cooz2), adapted for Excel by [LucasHol](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/lucashol) | https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive | 0/46 |
| 3 | [Julio Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86756087) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/74360506/12287457 | 0/46 |
| 4 | [Claude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9970021) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/64657459/12287457 | 0/46 |
| 5 | [Variatus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7675437) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/68568909/12287457 | 0/46 |
| 6 | [MatChrupczalski](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/matchrupczalski) | https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive | 1/46 |
| 7 | [Caio Silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11824550) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/67318424/12287457 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67326133/12287457 | 2/46 |
| 8 | [Alain YARDIM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15111552) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967886/12287457 | 2/46 |
| 9 | [tsdn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7889517) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326922/12287457 | 2/46 |
| 10 | [Peter G. Schild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196810) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990170/12287457 | 2/46 |
| 11 | [TWMIC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14542463) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/64591370/12287457 | 3/46 |
| 12 | [Horoman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039879) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921115/12287457 | 4/46 |
| 13 | [Philip Swannell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5686920) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/54182663/12287457 | 4/46 |
| 14 | [RMK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223251) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697487/12287457 | 5/46 |
| 15 | [beerockxs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15959050) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/67582367/12287457 | 5/46 |
| 16 | [Virtuoso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847477) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935405/12287457 | 5/46 |
| 17 | [COG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2330009) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/51316641/12287457 | 5/46 |
| 18 | [mohnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100979) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569925/12287457 | 5/46 |
| 19 | [Tomoaki Tsuruya (鶴谷 朋亮)](https://tsurutoro.com/profile/) | https://tsurutoro.com/vba-trouble2/ | 5/46 |
| 20 | [Greedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6609896) | [https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/ 52eaccd25814b84cc62cbeab9574d7a3](https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/52eaccd25814b84cc62cbeab9574d7a3) | 6/45 |
| 21 | [Christoph Ackermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8548145) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742852/12287457 | 6/46 |
| 22 | [Schoentalegg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11786481) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040668/12287457 | 6/46 |
| 23 | [Erlandsen Data Consulting](https://www.erlandsendata.no) | https://www.erlandsendata.no/?t=vbatips&p=4079 | 7/46 |
| 24 | [Kurobako (黒箱)](https://kuroihako.com/profile/) | https://kuroihako.com/vba/onedriveurltolocalpath/ | 7/46 |
| 25 | [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610729/12287457 | 8/46 |
| 26 | [Erik van der Neut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314230) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/72709568/12287457 | 8/46 |
| 27 | [Ricardo Diaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521579) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/65605893/12287457 | 9/46 |
| 28 | [Iksi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16773412) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/68963896/12287457 | 11/46 |
| 29 | [Gustav Brock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527297), Cactus Data ApS | https://stackoverflow.com/a/70521246/12287457 | 11/46 |
| 30 | [Ricardo Gerbaudo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7011129) | https://stackoverflow.com/a/69929678/12287457 | 14/46 |
| 31 | Guido Witt-Dörring Short solution | https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457 | 24/46 |
| 32 | [Ion Cristian Buse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8488913) | https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools | 46/46 |
| 33 | Guido Witt-Dörring Universal Solution | [https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/ 038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d) | 46/46 |

Each line in the table in the below image represents one solution in the above table and they can be correlated using the solution number.
Likewise, each column represents a test case, they can be correlated to this [test-table](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d#file-testtable-md) by using the test-number. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't allow answers long enough to include the table of test cases directly in this post.

[image: Test result data]

> <sup>All of this testing was done on Windows. On macOS, every solution except for [Nr 32](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools) and [Nr 33](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d) would pass 0/46 tests. The solutions presented in this post (#32 and #33) also pass every test on macOS.</sup>

Most solutions pass very few tests. Many of these tests are relatively difficult to solve, some are absolute edge cases, such as tests Nr 41 to 46, that test how a solution deals with OneDrive folders that are synced to multiple different local paths, which can only happen if multiple Business OneDrive accounts are logged in on the same PC and even then needs some special setup. (More information on that can be found here in [Thread 2](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools/issues/2))

Test Nr 22 contains various Unicode emoji characters in some folder names, this is why many solutions fail with error here.

If you have another different solution you would like me to test, let me know and I'll add it to this section.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks to both of you for your thorough investigation and analysis, and even more for sharing such a detailed solution.

Comment: Super clear and shows the effort you put to solve this. Well done and thanks for sharing it!

Comment: I would be curious if you were also able to add my approach to the tests https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/52eaccd25814b84cc62cbeab9574d7a3 it uses the registry like many others but I want to know the limitations of it in your test suite, as well as performance. (I know for example it fails in some top-level scenario I can't remember how to recreate)

Comment: Unfortunately, every time I have to add something to this post it is a bit difficult as it is constantly scraping at the 30 000 character limit. Are you planning to adapt your solution still or should I add it as it is now?

Comment: @GWD Thanks so much for running those tests, no I won't update I'll just use one of yours! I'm not surprised I didn't try many edge cases, just wanted a friendly API. If you don't mind adding it to the table as it is that would still be great, that way I can tell in what circumstances it fails. PS the `ConvertToLocalPath` UDF will return a variant rather than raising an error which may make it easier to run tests.

Comment: If anyone else is wondering you can call this from Excel using `=GetLocalPath(CELL("filename",$A$1))`

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability Thanks for the note but that would be Excel only while the solutions presented here are working in any host Application. Moreover, the solutions work with any path regardless of the OneDrive folder or the SharePoint folder (if sharing a Teams folder for example) while ```CELL``` would only be applicable to the current workbook - just saying there are uses outside translating the path of the current workbook.

Comment: Are you able to share a test workbook? I imagine many of the sets require hand crafted env setups but it would still be interesting to see how the tests are run and the types of paths used. Sorry this may be a big ask

Comment: Hi @Greedo, I think my test workbook would be of relatively limited use to you since as you said, all of the OneDrive syncs need to be set up manually. You can find all of the paths used in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d#file-testtable-md). I have a test function that accepts as input the URL path and the corresponding local path(s) and it compares the expected local path(s) with the output of `GetLocalPath(UrlPath)` and the code is generally very messy. If you would still want to see it, I can send you something via email.

Comment: @Greedo, If you are interested in helping us repair the solution for 23.184.0903.0001 and newer that would be very welcome. It seems to be possible by [reading some SQL files](https://github.com/Beercow/OneDriveExplorer/issues/14) to get the necessary information about the OneDrive folder structure, but doing so in a reliable cross-platform way with VBA might be a big challenge which I currently do not have the time for to deal with.

Comment: @GWD Yes You would need an sqlite driver installed https://stackoverflow.com/a/42512968/6609896 and then use the .db files in the folders inside `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings` then follow the method in https://github.com/Beercow/OneDriveExplorer/blob/421cdd154c9ea5336c20e2a47799309fdf768912/OneDriveExplorer/ode/parsers/sqlite_db.py#L25 (note the `sql_dir` is just one of the folders inside that settings dir)

Comment: @Greedo, Exactly, sounds like a lot of work and nearly impossible to achieve cross-platform ☹️ If you are interested in contributing I'd say we discuss any progress [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools/issues/17). This has already been one of the most complicated solutions for a seemingly simple problem, but it seems we will have to take it to another level once again...

Comment: @Greedo, I now think the .db files can be parsed manually without an SQL driver, similar to what we currently do with the .dat files. I think this will actually be easier to implement cross-platform. I'll work on this as soon as I have time!

Comment: @Greedo, we have now updated both solutions for the new OneDrive version. We did go down the path of parsing the .db files manually without SQL driver. Are you still interested in a test workbook as in your comment on the 12th of September?

Comment: This looks like a great effort. Thank you. Does anyone maybe has a ported c# solution?

Comment: @GWD I'm currently making an implementation in C#, where I obviously can use standard SQLite APIs. I've inspected the tables, but one particular data point seems to be missing - namely how to discover that a mounted folder is a (deeply nested) folder. I'm referring to the fact than any folder can be sync'ed locally, but I am unable to find the data required to tell me its path to the top-level directory. Consequently, all synced folders _appear_ as top level folders. Could I prevail upon you to point me in the right direction in e.g. your gist?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderHøst, very interesting! This will probably require further discussion, do you have it in a repository on GitHub? A short answer to this question: Every folder has a FolderID and ParentFolderID, i can't tell you how the fields are called unfortunately. The IDs have different formats for business and personal OneDrive but they can be used to build the full folder paths of the server side folder structure.

Comment: @GWD Unfortunately don't have it public (client code), but the solution was to use SyncEngineDatabase.db in the OneDrive settings folder, and read from the `od_ClientFolder_Records` table. You can indeed reconstruct the full remote folder paths using ResourceId and ParentResourceId as you point out, which is quite trivial.

Answer (score 15):

I found a thread online which contained enough information to put something simple together to solve this. I actually implemented the solution in Ruby, but this is the VBA version:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function Local_Workbook_Name(ByRef wb As Workbook) As String

  Dim Ctr As Long
  Dim objShell As Object
  Dim UserProfilePath As String

  'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
  If InStr(1, wb.FullName, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    'Replace forward slashes with back slashes
    Local_Workbook_Name = Replace(wb.FullName, "/", "\")

    'Get environment path using vbscript
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    UserProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

      'Trim OneDrive designators
    For Ctr = 1 To 4
       Local_Workbook_Name = Mid(Local_Workbook_Name, InStr(Local_Workbook_Name, "\") + 1)
    Next

      'Construct the name
    Local_Workbook_Name = UserProfilePath & "\OneDrive\" & Local_Workbook_Name

  Else

    Local_Workbook_Name = wb.FullName

  End If

End Function

Private Sub testy()

  MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbCrLf & Local_Workbook_Name(ActiveWorkbook)

End Sub
```

Comment: I modified testy () as follows, now I can just enter into a cell =testy() and get a full path to my file.
`Function testy() As String
  testy = Local_Workbook_Name(ActiveWorkbook)
End Function`
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, your answer saved my day 

Comment: The only reliable solution that will always indicate the correct path even if there are multiple file copies in different OneDrive folders is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697487/6097926

Answer (score 13):

[Horoman's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921115/6908282) (2020-03-30) is good because it works on both private and commercial OneDrive. However it crashed on me because the line "LocalFullName = oneDrivePath & Application.PathSeparator & endFilePath" inserts a slash between oneDrivePath & endFilePath. Moreover, one should really try out paths "OneDriveCommercial" and "OneDriveConsumer" before "OneDrive". So here's the code that works for me:

```
Sub TestLocalFullName()
    Debug.Print "URL: " & ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Debug.Print "Local: " & LocalFullName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
    Debug.Print "Test: " & Dir(LocalFullName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName))
End Sub

Private Function LocalFullName$(ByVal fullPath$)
    'Finds local path for a OneDrive file URL, using environment variables of OneDrive
    'Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive
    'Authors: Philip Swannell 2019-01-14, MatChrupczalski 2019-05-19, Horoman 2020-03-29, P.G.Schild 2020-04-02

    Dim ii&
    Dim iPos&
    Dim oneDrivePath$
    Dim endFilePath$

    If Left(fullPath, 8) = "https://" Then 'Possibly a OneDrive URL
        If InStr(1, fullPath, "my.sharepoint.com") <> 0 Then 'Commercial OneDrive
            'For commercial OneDrive, path looks like "https://companyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/userName_domain_com/Documents" & file.FullName)
            'Find "/Documents" in string and replace everything before the end with OneDrive local path
            iPos = InStr(1, fullPath, "/Documents") + Len("/Documents") 'find "/Documents" position in file URL
            endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, iPos) 'Get the ending file path without pointer in OneDrive. Include leading "/"
        Else 'Personal OneDrive
            'For personal OneDrive, path looks like "https://d.docs.live.net/d7bbaa#######1/" & file.FullName
            'We can get local file path by replacing "https.." up to the 4th slash, with the OneDrive local path obtained from registry
            iPos = 8 'Last slash in https://
            For ii = 1 To 2
                iPos = InStr(iPos + 1, fullPath, "/") 'find 4th slash
            Next ii
            endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, iPos) 'Get the ending file path without OneDrive root. Include leading "/"
        End If
        endFilePath = Replace(endFilePath, "/", Application.PathSeparator) 'Replace forward slashes with back slashes (URL type to Windows type)
        For ii = 1 To 3 'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
            oneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(ii, "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer", "OneDrive")) 'Check possible local paths. "OneDrive" should be the last one
            If 0 < Len(oneDrivePath) Then
                LocalFullName = oneDrivePath & endFilePath
                Exit Function 'Success (i.e. found the correct Environ parameter)
            End If
        Next ii
        'Possibly raise an error here when attempt to convert to a local file name fails - e.g. for "shared with me" files
        LocalFullName = vbNullString
    Else
        LocalFullName = fullPath
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: For instances where `fullPath = %OneDrive%`, or equivalent, the `endFilePath` lines should be `endFilePath = IIf(iPos = 0, "", Mid(wbPath, iPos))`

Comment: How to use this VBS? I opened Visual Basic and saved your script as a module. Then I closed Visual Basic and entered into a cell =TestLocalFullName(). But it returns an error.

Comment: I'm confused; if you've just worked out that the https link is Commercial vs Consumer, why do you try every `Environ` result, and not just `Environ("OneDriveCommercial")` and `Environ("OneDriveConsumer")` respectively, maybe then falling back to `Environ("OneDrive")` if both fail. It feels like a Commercial file could overwrite a consumer one if it has the same name - even if the original link was the `"https://d.docs.live.net..."` style?

Answer (score 12):

### Short solution

The solution presented in the following does not work in absolutely all cases, but it probably works in more than 99% of real-world scenarios. If you are looking for a solution that covers even the edge cases, please look at this [universal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

An advantage of this solution compared to the above linked universal solution is its simplicity and therefore its lower likelihood to break because of OneDrive/Windows updates.

The function to convert the "`WebPath`" to a local path looks like this:

```vb
Public Function GetLocalPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    Const HKCU = &H80000001
    Dim objReg As Object, rPath As String, subKeys(), subKey
    Dim urlNamespace As String, mountPoint As String, secPart As String
    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\." & _
                           "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    rPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    objReg.EnumKey HKCU, rPath, subKeys
    For Each subKey In subKeys
        objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "UrlNamespace", urlNamespace
        If InStr(Path, urlNamespace) > 0 Then
            objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "MountPoint", mountPoint
            secPart = Replace(Mid(Path, Len(urlNamespace)), "/", "\")
            Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Do Until Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Or InStr(2, secPart, "\") = 0
                secPart = Mid(secPart, InStr(2, secPart, "\"))
                Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetLocalPath = Path
End Function
```

To now get the local full name of your workbook, just use `GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)`

Comment: This solution worked for me when the Solution 2 by @GWD did not work.  My fullpath from Excel is as follows:
https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_domain_com/Documents/Documents/ExportTemplate.xlsx

Comment: Hi @Ben, I'm very curious to find out why the universal solution failed! Did you also try Cristian Buses [library](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools)? If so, does it fail too? I'll try to investigate next week, I'd be very grateful if you can run some tests then, I'll let you know as soon as I have something!

Comment: Hi @Ben, I have updated the code of my [universal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) to hopefully fix the rare out-of-memory bug you reported. Please test the new version and let me know if it works now on your system!

Comment: I just re-tested your updated *Universal Solution 2* from 10-Mar-23 and it now works in my environment.  I will make a switch to that version.

Comment: This work for me now.

Guido Witt-Dörring Short solution used to work but onedrive update 23 Nov 2023 - 30 Nov 2023 failed it.

Comment: @navafolk, I'm not sure what you mean, this IS the solution linked under "Guido Witt-Dörring Short solution". Which solution fails now and which works? If you meant to say that the "universal solution" now fails, I encourage you to update the code to the latest version because it was updated about two months ago to take into account the breaking change which said OneDrive update introduced. So please try the current code from [here](https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d).

Comment: Will this work if the file was dragged and dropped to a commercial OneDrive from a personal folder? In that case the url refers back to the personal folder… I think it also gets some funny things into the url.

Comment: @sjb-sjb, can you give me an example of how the resulting URL is structured? You can hide/replace personal information of course. This does not work for URLs generated with the "Share" functionality, but I don't know how drag-and-drop is supposed to introduce funny things into the URL.

Comment: Sorry @GWD I did not capture it at the time. After some thought I've concluded that for me the best approach is to avoid this whole problem by organizing the interface so that no URLs are involved.

Answer (score 9):

I have adjusted the function provided by others to account for some additional constraints:

- When you share files via a team site, it's not "my.sharepoint.com/" but "sharepoint.com/" that you should use to determine if it's a commercial version.
- It is better to count the slashes rather than using the position of "/Documents" because, for example in French, the document folder is called "Documents partages". It is preferable to count 4 slashes for commercial use and 2 slashes for personal use.
- If the SharePoint folder added as a shortcut to OneDrive is not at the root, the local address on the hard drive does not contain parent folders on the SharePoint.

Here is the code that takes my changes into account:

```
Public Function AdresseLocal$(ByVal fullPath$)
    'Finds local path for a OneDrive file URL, using environment variables of OneDrive
    'Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive
    'Authors: Philip Swannell 2019-01-14, MatChrupczalski 2019-05-19, Horoman 2020-03-29, P.G.Schild 2020-04-02
    Dim ii&
    Dim iPos&
    Dim oneDrivePath$
    Dim endFilePath$
    Dim NbSlash
    
    If Left(fullPath, 8) = "https://" Then
        If InStr(1, fullPath, "sharepoint.com/") <> 0 Then 'Commercial OneDrive
            NbSlash = 4
        Else 'Personal OneDrive
            NbSlash = 2
        End If
        iPos = 8 'Last slash in https://
        For ii = 1 To NbSlash
            iPos = InStr(iPos + 1, fullPath, "/")
        Next ii
        endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, iPos)
        endFilePath = Replace(endFilePath, "/", Application.PathSeparator)
        For ii = 1 To 3
            oneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(ii, "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer", "OneDrive"))
            If 0 < Len(oneDrivePath) Then Exit For
        Next ii
        AdresseLocal = oneDrivePath & endFilePath
        While Len(Dir(AdresseLocal, vbDirectory)) = 0 And InStr(2, endFilePath, Application.PathSeparator) > 0
            endFilePath = Mid(endFilePath, InStr(2, endFilePath, Application.PathSeparator))
            AdresseLocal = oneDrivePath & endFilePath
        Wend
    Else
        AdresseLocal = fullPath
    End If
End Function
```

...which builds on the work of the different contributors.

Comment: Just needs the "End Function" moving inside the code block, but this worked great when I had the same problem again :)

Comment: What do I need to pass as the argument for the function - `ByVal fullPath$`? Is it just `ActiveWorkbook.Path`?

Comment: @Mistakamikaze Pass in `ThisWorkbook.Path` for the parent directory, `ThisWorkbook.FullName` for the file itself

Comment: @Alain Yardim Hi, thanks for the function. Could you explain a little more about the point saying " if the SharePoint folder added as a shortcut to OneDrive is not at the root, the local address on the hard drive does not contain parent folders on the SharePoint" - what's an example of the kind of full path url you might see? What is the purpose of the final While loop - it only ever seems to loop once so it could just be an if statement and run one time. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: There could be a folder called "sharepoint.com" inside a Personal OneDrive and then the logic presented here would fail because the path being passed to the method will contain the folder "sharepoint.com/". Better is to search the "sharepoint" keyword with ```InStr(1, Mid$(path_, 9, InStr(9, path_, "/") - 9), "sharepoint", vbTextCompare) > 0``` so that only the root is checked.

Comment: This solution will fail on many occassions. Here is the only fully reliable one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697487/6097926

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to improve on Virtuoso's answer to reduce (though not eliminate) the chance that the function returns a "wrong" file location. The problem is that there are various URLs that a workbook's `.FullName` can be. These are three I'm aware of:

1. A URL associated with the user's OneDrive
2. A URL associated with the user's OneDrive for Business
3. A URL associated with somebody else's OneDrive in the case that that other person has "shared" the file (in which case you open the file via File > Open > Shared with me)

On my PC I can get the relevant local folders to map the first two URLs via the `OneDriveConsumer` and `OneDriveCommercial` environment variables, that exist in addition to the `OneDrive` environment variable, so the code below makes use of these. I'm not aware that it's possible to handle the "Shared with Me" files and the code below will return their `https://`-style location.

```
Private Function Local_Workbook_Name(ByRef wb As Workbook) As String

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim OneDrivePath As String
    Dim ShortName As String

    'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
    If InStr(1, wb.FullName, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Replace forward slashes with back slashes
        ShortName = Replace(wb.FullName, "/", "\")

        'Remove the first four backslashes
        For i = 1 To 4
            ShortName = Mid(ShortName, InStr(ShortName, "\") + 1)
        Next

        'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
        For j = 1 To 3
            OneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(j, "OneDrive", "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer"))
            If Len(OneDrivePath) > 0 Then
                Local_Workbook_Name = OneDrivePath & "\" & ShortName
                If Dir(Local_Workbook_Name) <> "" Then
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        'Possibly raise an error here when attempt to convert to a local file name fails - e.g. for "shared with me" files
    End If

    Local_Workbook_Name = wb.FullName

End Function
```

Unfortunately, if files exist with identical paths within both the OneDrive folder and the OneDrive for Business folder, then the code can't distinguish between them, and may return the "wrong one". I don't have a solution for that.

Answer (score 6):

Easy Fix (early 2019) - For anyone else having this issue:

OneDrive > Settings > Office:
    - Uncheck 'Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open'

This lets excel save the file in the typical "C:\Users[UserName]\OneDrive..." file format instead of the UNC "https:\" format.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if you have AutoSave=Off (trigerred by clearing your checkbox). Once i turn it back On - it tries to sync directly to OneDrive again and FullName agains refers to https :(

Comment: Even with autosave off the workbook path is on SharePoint (Oct 2019)

Answer (score 6):

I like the Version from TWMIC with the use of the Registry. All other Version did not work at my oneDrive for Business. There are some folders where the name is slightly different to the URL, for example in the URL are partly no spaces but in the folder there are. If it is from Teams and in the Team Name are spaces then this is a problem. Even the Folder Names from Teams are different than the URL, depending which folder level in Teams you are syncing.

The Version from TWMIC is tagged as dangerous at my work computer and i can't use it, very sad about that.
So i made a Version which reads the ini File from oneDrive for Busines, if it is OneDrive for Business...

```
Public Function AdresseLocal$(ByVal fullPath$)
'Finds local path for a OneDrive file URL, using environment variables of OneDrive and loading the settings ini File of OneDrive
'Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive
'Authors: Philip Swannell 2019-01-14, MatChrupczalski 2019-05-19, Horoman 2020-03-29, P.G.Schild 2020-04-02, Iksi 2021-08-28
Dim ScreenUpdate As Boolean
Dim ii&
Dim iPos&
Dim DatFile$, SettingsDir$, Temp$
Dim oneDrivePath$, oneDriveURL$
Dim endFilePath$

If Left(fullPath, 8) = "https://" Then
    If InStr(1, fullPath, "sharepoint.com") <> 0 Then 'Commercial OneDrive
        'Find the correct settings File, I'm not sure if it is always in Folder Business1, so trying to find a Folder Business and then Business1, 2 ....
        'First find *.dat File, seems to be only one of that type, the correct ini File is the same Name than the dat File
        DatFile = Dir(Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business\*.dat")
        If DatFile <> "" Then SettingsDir = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business\"
        For ii = 1 To 9
            Temp = Dir(Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business" & ii & "\*.dat")
            If Temp <> "" Then
                If SettingsDir = "" Then
                    DatFile = Temp
                    SettingsDir = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & "\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business" & ii & "\"
                Else
                    MsgBox "There is more than one OneDrive settings Folder!"
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'Open ini File without showing
        ScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
            SettingsDir & Left(DatFile, Len(DatFile) - 3) & "ini" _
            , Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier _
            :=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:= _
            False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        ii = 1
        Do While Cells(ii, 1) = "libraryScope"
        'Search the correct URL which fits to the fullPath and then search the corresponding Folder
            If InStr(fullPath, Cells(ii, 9)) = 1 Then
                oneDriveURL = Cells(ii, 9)
                If Cells(ii, 15) <> "" Then
                    oneDrivePath = Cells(ii, 15)
                Else
                    iPos = Cells(ii, 3)
                    Do Until Cells(ii, 1) = "libraryFolder"
                        ii = ii + 1
                    Loop
                    Do While Cells(ii, 1) = "libraryFolder"
                        If Cells(ii, 4) = iPos Then
                            oneDrivePath = Cells(ii, 7)
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        ii = ii + 1
                    Loop
                End If
                Exit Do
            End If
            ii = ii + 1
        Loop
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdate
        
        endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, Len(oneDriveURL) + 1)
        
    Else 'Personal OneDrive
        'For personal OneDrive, path looks like "https://d.docs.live.net/d7bbaa#######1/" & file.FullName
        'We can get local file path by replacing "https.." up to the 4th slash, with the OneDrive local path obtained from registry
        iPos = 8 'Last slash in https://
        For ii = 1 To 2
            iPos = InStr(iPos + 1, fullPath, "/") 'find 4th slash
        Next ii
        endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, iPos) 'Get the ending file path without OneDrive root. Include leading "/"
    End If
    endFilePath = Replace(endFilePath, "/", Application.PathSeparator)
    If Len(oneDrivePath) <= 0 Then
        For ii = 1 To 3 'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
            oneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(ii, "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer", "OneDrive")) 'Check possible local paths. "OneDrive" should be the last one
        Next ii
    End If
    
    AdresseLocal = oneDrivePath & endFilePath
    While Len(Dir(AdresseLocal, vbDirectory)) = 0 And InStr(2, endFilePath, Application.PathSeparator) > 0
        endFilePath = Mid(endFilePath, InStr(2, endFilePath, Application.PathSeparator))
        AdresseLocal = oneDrivePath & endFilePath
    Wend
Else
    AdresseLocal = fullPath
End If
End Function
```

For me this works great!

Comment: Yes...it's awesome..thanks for sharing!

Comment: I suggest adding Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) after       Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdate as I was getting an error. This delay fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

Very helpful, thanks. I had a similar issue, but with a folder name rather than a filename. Consequently I modified it slightly. I made it work for folder names AND filenames (doesn't have to be a workbook).  In case it's helpful, code is below:

```
Public Function Local_Name(theName As String) As String
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim objShell        As Object
    Dim UserProfilePath As String

    ' Check if it looks like a OneDrive location.
    If InStr(1, theName, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        ' Replace forward slashes with back slashes.
        Local_Name = Replace(theName, "/", "\")

        'Get environment path using vbscript.
        Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        UserProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

        ' Trim OneDrive designators.
        For i = 1 To 4
            Local_Name = Mid(Local_Name, InStr(Local_Name, "\") + 1)
        Next i

        ' Construct the name.
        Local_Name = UserProfilePath & "\OneDrive\" & Local_Name
    Else
        ' (must already be local).
        Local_Name = theName
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Nice improvement, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: You can directly access the OneDrive path using 
objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%OneDrive%")

Comment: Didn't quite work for me. When executed with `ActiveWorkbook.path` it returns `C:\Users\deepstop\OneDrive\deepstop_idc_com\Documents\Shared with Noone\etc\etc`, in which neither `deepstop_idc_com` nor `Documents` are in fact part of the path.

Answer (score 4):

This is really great stuff.  I have run into this problem on some windows 10 machines but not others and it seems to come and go.  I tried everything resetting OneDrive, changing the configuration etc.  The only thing I tried that at least works on my machine is to use `Fullname=CurDir` & `FileName`, instead of `FullName= activeworkbook.Path` & `FileName`.

This returned the full local name without the https stuff and I was able to open my file ok.

Comment: This is a bit risky as it depends on the shell environment matching the workbook location, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the variable **ThisWorkbook.Path** use **Environ("OneDrive")**.

```
Option Explicit
'
Function TransferURL(wbkURL As String) As String
' Converts the URL of a OneDrive into a path.
' Returns the path's name.
    
    Dim oFs As Object
    Dim oFl As Object
    Dim oSubFl As Object
 
    Dim pos As Integer
    Dim pathPart As String
    Dim oneDrive As String
    Dim subFl As String
        
    Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
    ' Check the version of OneDrive.
    If VBA.InStr(1, _
                 VBA.UCase(wbkURL), "MY.SHAREPOINT.COM") = 0 Then
        
        oneDrive = "OneDriveConsumer"
        
    Else
        
        oneDrive = "OneDriveCommercial"
        
    End If
    
    Set oFl = oFs.GetFolder(Environ(oneDrive))
    
    ' Iteration over OneDrive's subfolders.
    For Each oSubFl In oFl.SUBFOLDERS
        
        subFl = "/" & VBA.Mid(oSubFl.Path, _
                              VBA.Len(Environ(oneDrive)) + 2) & "/"
    
        ' Check if part of the URL.
        If VBA.InStr(1, _
                     wbkURL, subFl) > 0 Then
                
            ' Determine the path after OneDrive's folder.
            pos = VBA.InStr(1, _
                            wbkURL, subFl)
        
            pathPart = VBA.Mid(VBA.Replace(wbkURL, "/", _
                                           Application.PathSeparator), pos)
        
        End If
    
    Next
    
    TransferURL = Environ(oneDrive) & pathPart

End Function
```

Call the function by:

```
' Check if path specification as URL.
If VBA.Left(VBA.UCase(oWbk.Path), _
            5) = "HTTPS" Then

    ' Call ...
    pathName = TransferURL(oWbk.Path)

End If
```

The differentiation between OneDriveConsumer and OneDriveCommercial is derived from:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive?forum=officegeneral

Edited by MatChrupczalski Thursday, May 9, 2019 5:45 PM

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as you.
But I have solved that problem.
The first I turn off OneDrive before I running the script.

you can add this script on the first script into your vba/module:

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /C" & "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /shutdown")
```

and then, on your last script on your vba/module you can insert this for activate your OneDrive:

```
Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /C" & "start %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe /background")
```

I am using Windows10 on that script.

Comment: A bit more extreme than I was going for, but a good idea. You'd have to watch out for exceptions and make sure you didn't leave it disabled.

Answer (score 3):

```
Option Explicit

Private coll_Locations As Collection            ' using Collection but could just as easily use Dictionary
Public Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
'

Public Function getOneDrv_PathFor(ByVal sPath As String, Optional ByVal sType As String = "") As String
' convert start of passed in path from URL to Local or vice.versa, (for OneDrive Sync'd folders)
' sType : if starts L(ocal) return local path, if starts U(rl) then return URL Path, else return other mode to that passed in
    Dim sPathNature As String
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim Slash As String, Slash2 As String
    
    getOneDrv_PathFor = sPath ' return unchanged if no action required or recognised
    
    sType = UCase(Left(sType, 1))
    If sType <> "L" And sType <> "U" Then sType = ""
    sPathNature = IIf(Left(sPath, 4) = "http", "U", "L")
    If sType <> "" And sType = sPathNature Then Exit Function  ' nothing to do
    
    If coll_Locations Is Nothing Then get_Locations
    
    For Each vKey In coll_Locations
        If InStr(1, sPath, vKey, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            Slash = IIf(sPathNature = "U", "/", "\")
            Slash2 = IIf(Slash = "/", "\", "/")
            getOneDrv_PathFor = coll_Locations(vKey) & Replace(Mid(sPath, Len(vKey) + 1), Slash, Slash2)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Function


Private Sub get_Locations()
' collect possible OneDrive: URL vs Local paths

    Dim oWMI As Object
    Dim sRegPath As String, arrSubKeys() As Variant, vSubKey As Variant
    Dim sServiceEndPointUri As String, sUserFolder As String

    Set coll_Locations = New Collection

    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    sRegPath = "Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\"
    oWMI.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sRegPath, arrSubKeys
    
    For Each vSubKey In arrSubKeys
        oWMI.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sRegPath & vSubKey, "ServiceEndPointUri", sServiceEndPointUri
        oWMI.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sRegPath & vSubKey, "UserFolder", sUserFolder
        If sServiceEndPointUri <> "" And sUserFolder <> "" Then
            If Right(sServiceEndPointUri, 5) = "/_api" Then sServiceEndPointUri = Left(sServiceEndPointUri, Len(sServiceEndPointUri) - 4) & "Documents/"
            sUserFolder = sUserFolder & "\"
            coll_Locations.Add Item:=sServiceEndPointUri, Key:=sUserFolder
            coll_Locations.Add Item:=sUserFolder, Key:=sServiceEndPointUri
        End If
    Next
    'listOneDrv_Locations
  
    Set oWMI = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub listOneDrv_Locations()
    ' to list what's in the collection
     Dim vKey As Variant
    ' Set coll_Locations = Nothing
    If coll_Locations Is Nothing Then get_Locations
    For Each vKey In coll_Locations
        Debug.Print vKey, coll_Locations(vKey)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then to get the LocalPath would be
strLocalPath = getOneDrv_PathFor(strCurrentPath, "Local")

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was tagged with VBA, but I found this while I was trying to solve with C#.  I wrote a version similar to @TWMIC answer as the following:

```cs
string LocalPath( string fullPath )
{
    if ( fullPath.StartsWith( "https://", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) )
    {
        // So Documents/ location works below
        fullPath = fullPath.Replace( "\\", "/" );
        
        var userAccounts = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser
            .OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\");

        if (userAccounts != null)
        {
            foreach (var accountName in userAccounts.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                var account = userAccounts.OpenSubKey(accountName);
                var endPoint = account.GetValue("ServiceEndPointUri") as string;
                var userFolder = account.GetValue("UserFolder") as string;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userFolder))
                {
                    if (endPoint.EndsWith("/_api"))
                    {
                        endPoint = endPoint.Substring(0, endPoint.Length - 4) + "documents/";
                    }

                    if (fullPath.StartsWith(endPoint, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        return Path.Combine(userFolder, fullPath.Substring(endPoint.Length));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return fullPath;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Alternative Solution

I have recently found a new unique solution to this problem and because it is currently not described anywhere online I'd like to point it out here.

Microsoft recently added a new button to the Excel UI for OneDrive synchronized workbooks.

[image: Copy local path button in the Excel UI]

Clicking it copies the local path to the clipboard. This is the first official Microsoft solution for this problem I know of.

Unfortunately, this functionality is not (yet?) part of the object model, hence, to get this info in VBA, the button must be clicked by the code. This is possible but isn't 100% reliable. An example of how to do this looks like this:

```vb
Public Function GetLocalPathOfWorkbook(Optional ByVal wb As Workbook = Nothing) _
                                       As String
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    GetLocalPathOfWorkbook = wb.FullName
    If Not wb.FullName Like "http*" Or wb.FullName = "" Then Exit Function

    With Application
        Dim appScreenUpdating As Boolean: appScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        Dim appEnableEvents As Boolean: appEnableEvents = .EnableEvents
        Dim appDisplayAlerts As Boolean: appDisplayAlerts = .DisplayAlerts
        .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    With wb.Windows(1)
        Dim wbVisible As Boolean: wbVisible = .Visible
        Dim wbWindowState As XlWindowState: wbWindowState = .WindowState
        
        If Not .Visible Then .Visible = True
        If .WindowState = xlMinimized Then .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Activate
    End With
    On Error GoTo RestoreAppState

    SendKeys "%f", True 'Weirdly, both, the SendKeys and the CommandBars.Execute
    SendKeys "%i", True 'are necessary for the code to run reliably, even though
                        'they (should) just do the same thing twice in theory?
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FileProperties" 
    SendKeys "%l", True
    SendKeys "{ESC}", True
    DoEvents
    GetLocalPathOfWorkbook = _
        CreateObject("HtmlFile").parentWindow.clipboardData.GetData("text")

RestoreAppState:
    wb.Windows(1).WindowState = wbWindowState
    wb.Windows(1).Visible = wbVisible
    Application.ScreenUpdating = appScreenUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = appEnableEvents
    Application.DisplayAlerts = appDisplayAlerts

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err
End Function
```

Unfortunately, this code sometimes randomly stops at the `DoEvents` line with the message "Code execution was interrupted.". This is very annoying, especially because clicking `Debug` and then `Continue` will let the code finish without further issues.

Since this solution uses `SendKeys` and UI automation it can also cause other random unforeseen problems or fail if the user interacts with the app while the code is running. Sometimes, issues even occur without external user interaction.

Apart from these drawbacks, this method is actually pretty powerful and can even be used to get the local path of any OneDrive/SharePoint "web path". (A "web path" is a link that's not a "share link")
This is possible because the `Workbook.SaveAs` method supports OneDrive URLs. Therefore, to find the local path, we can use code to create a temporary workbook in a location, open it, use the above-defined function, close it, and delete it again.

In the following, I've implemented a proof of concept to show that this works for arbitrary paths (Only if they exist!):

```vb
Public Function GetLocalPath(ByVal path As String)
    GetLocalPath = path
    If Not path Like "http*" Or path = "" Then Exit Function
    Dim testWbName As String: testWbName = RandomStringAlphanumeric(6)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'Find out if path is a file or folder
    Dim isFile As Boolean
    If Not Right(path, 1) = "/" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        wb.SaveAs path & "/" & testWbName
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            wb.Saved = True 'The file that failed saving must be closed because
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=xlDoNotSaveChanges 'next save attempt fails
            Set wb = Nothing
            isFile = True
        End If
    End If

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

    'Save the test file if not already saved
    On Error GoTo SaveFailed
    If isFile Then
        wb.SaveAs Left(path, InStrRev(path, "/")) & testWbName
    ElseIf Right(path, 1) = "/" Then
        wb.SaveAs path & testWbName
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Get local path, close and delete file
    Dim localTempFileFullName As String, localTempFilePath As String
    localTempFileFullName = GetLocalPathOfWorkbook(wb)
    localTempFilePath = Left(localTempFileFullName, InStrRev(localTempFileFullName, "\"))
    wb.Saved = True
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=xlDoNotSaveChanges
    On Error GoTo DeleteFailed
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile localTempFileFullName
    On Error GoTo 0
    If isFile Then
        GetLocalPath = localTempFilePath & Mid(path, InStrRev(path, "/") + 1)
    Else
        If Right(path, 1) = "/" Then
            GetLocalPath = localTempFilePath
        Else
            GetLocalPath = Left(localTempFilePath, Len(localTempFilePath) - 1)
        End If
    End If
    Exit Function
SaveFailed:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        wb.Saved = True
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=xlDoNotSaveChanges
        Exit Function
    End If
    Err.Raise Err
    Exit Function
DeleteFailed:
    MsgBox "GetLocalPath failed to get the local path of '" & path & "'" & _
           vbNewLine & "A temporary file named " & testWbName & ".xlsx was " & _
           "created in the location '" & path & "', please delete it manually." _
           , vbCritical
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "GetLocalPath", _
              "Failed to delete this file: " & path & testWbName
End Function

Private Function RandomStringAlphanumeric(ByVal Length As Long) As String
    Dim b() As Byte, i As Long, char As Long: Randomize
    If Length < 1 Then Exit Function
    ReDim b(0 To Length * 2 - 1)
    For i = 0 To Length - 1
        Select Case Rnd
            Case Is < 0.41935: Do: char = 25 * Rnd + 65: Loop Until char <> 0
            Case Is < 0.83871: Do: char = 25 * Rnd + 97: Loop Until char <> 0
            Case Else: Do: char = 9 * Rnd + 48: Loop Until char <> 0
        End Select
        b(2 * i) = (Int(char)) And 255
    Next i
    RandomStringAlphanumeric = b
End Function
```

### Capabilities and Conclusion

Even though this method seems alluring as it is using an 'official' way of obtaining the local path without hacking around in the registry/settings files, it is, as of now, much less reliable than the [universal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457), which is currently marked as the accepted answer in this thread.

The main problems are, that it is very slow and error-prone, due to a large amount of UI automation involved in my attempted solution. Also, it doesn't work on Mac, as the backstage view is not available there.

Currently, I would much prefer the universal (currently accepted) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) in every possible scenario, its advantages are numerous:

- It doesn't use UI automation and therefore runs much, much faster, and more reliably. (If it runs once, it won't suddenly randomly fail as this solution might)
- It works on closed files and directories, and even for files and directories that don't exist (yet)
- It works as a user-defined function callable from the worksheet. From this post, only `GetLocalPathOfWorkbook` works like that too, `GetLocalPath` does not.
- It works on macOS. This solution does not.
- It doesn't mess with your clipboard, which this solution does.
- It doesn't require an internet connection to work for arbitrary paths, whereas `Workbook.SaveAs` as used in this post must save the file directly to OneDrive.
- In some cases `Workbook.SaveAs` fails, for example for paths with many more obscure Unicode characters that make the URL-encoded path exceedingly long. The universal solution from the accepted answer can deal with that.

To give an approximate idea of the capabilities of this method, in [the testing presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) it gets between 30 and 40 of 46 tests right and takes around 500 seconds. Importantly though, it can not complete a test run without user interaction because of the many randomly occurring errors. Also, there are some tests, that currently always fail.

In light of all the drawbacks of this method, even this [short solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457) is, by far, preferable.

If a more reliable way of clicking that button is found, without using `SendKeys` and physically navigating to the file info section, it could potentially be very useful in the future, especially on already open workbooks.
If anyone has some ideas on how to potentially do that, please let me know!

Comment: Thanks for adding that information. Hopefully that new solution will become available through the API soon!

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is a little bug in the code of JK2017: The"ShortName"-variable has to be rebuilt at every start of these 3 versions of OneDrive. So ist has to be inside the    'For i = 1 To 3'    loop.
I have also added the choise to get only the path instead of the full filename.

```
Private Function Local_Workbook_Name(ByRef wb As Workbook, Optional bPathOnly As Boolean = False) As String
'returns local wb path or nothing if local path not found
Dim i As Long, x As Long
Dim OneDrivePath As String
Dim ShortName As String
Dim testWbkPath As String
Dim OneDrivePathFound As Boolean

'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
If InStr(1, wb.FullName, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    'loop through three OneDrive options
    For i = 1 To 3
        'Replace forward slashes with back slashes
        ShortName = Replace(wb.FullName, "/", "\")

        'Remove the first four backslashes
        For x = 1 To 4
            ShortName = RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ShortName)
        Next
        'Choose the version of Onedrive
        OneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(i, "OneDrive", "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer"))
        If Len(OneDrivePath) > 0 Then
            'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
            Do While ShortName Like "*\*"
                testWbkPath = OneDrivePath & "\" & ShortName
                If Not (Dir(testWbkPath)) = vbNullString Then
                    OneDrivePathFound = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
                'remove top folder in path
                ShortName = RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ShortName)
            Loop
        End If
        If OneDrivePathFound Then Exit For
    Next i
Else
    If bPathOnly Then
        Local_Workbook_Name = RemoveFileNameFromPath(wb.FullName)
    Else
        Local_Workbook_Name = wb.FullName
    End If
End If
If OneDrivePathFound Then
        If bPathOnly Then
        Local_Workbook_Name = RemoveFileNameFromPath(testWbkPath)
    Else
        Local_Workbook_Name = testWbkPath
    End If
End If
End Function

Function RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ByVal ShortName As String) As String
   RemoveTopFolderFromPath = Mid(ShortName, InStr(ShortName, "\") + 1)
End Function

Function RemoveFileNameFromPath(ByVal ShortName As String) As String
   RemoveFileNameFromPath = Mid(ShortName, 1, Len(ShortName) - InStr(StrReverse(ShortName), "\"))
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The different number of slashes "/" could be related with different versions of OneDrive (private/professional). Compare MatChrupczalski post on the msdn website:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive?forum=officegeneral

Therefore I adapted the function to the following:

```
Sub TestMySolution()
  MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbCrLf & LocalFullName(ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
End Sub

' 29.03.2020 Horoman
' main parts by Philip Swannell 14.01.2019    
' combined with parts from MatChrupczalski 19.05.2019
' using environment variables of OneDrive
Private Function LocalFullName(ByVal fullPath As String) As String
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim oneDrivePath As String
  Dim endFilePath As String
  Dim iDocumentsPosition As Integer

  'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
  If InStr(1, fullPath, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    'for commercial OneDrive file path seems to be like "https://companyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/userName_domain_com/Documents" & file.FullName)
    If InStr(1, fullPath, "my.sharepoint.com") <> 0 Then
      'find "/Documents" in string and replace everything before the end with OneDrive local path
      iDocumentsPosition = InStr(1, fullPath, "/Documents") + Len("/Documents") 'find "/Documents" position in file URL
      endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, iDocumentsPosition)  'get the ending file path without pointer in OneDrive
    Else
      'for personal onedrive it looks like "https://d.docs.live.net/d7bbaa#######1/" & file.FullName, _
      '   by replacing "https.." with OneDrive local path obtained from registry we can get local file path
      'Remove the first four backslashes
      endFilePath = Mid(fullPath, 9) ' removes "https://" and with it two backslashes
      For i = 1 To 2
        endFilePath = Mid(endFilePath, InStr(endFilePath, "/") + 1)
      Next
    End If

    'Replace forward slashes with back slashes (URL type to Windows type)
    endFilePath = Replace(endFilePath, "/", Application.PathSeparator)

    'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
    For j = 1 To 3
      oneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(j, "OneDrive", "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer"))
      If Len(oneDrivePath) > 0 Then
          LocalFullName = oneDrivePath & Application.PathSeparator & endFilePath
          If Dir(LocalFullName) <> "" Then
            Exit Function 'that is it - WE GOT IT
          End If
      End If
    Next j
    'Possibly raise an error here when attempt to convert to a local file name fails - e.g. for "shared with me" files
    LocalFullName = ""
  End If

  LocalFullName = fullPath
End Function
```

Have fun.

Comment: Hey I'm a bit confused; if you have just worked out that this is a commercial link by finding  "my.sharepoint.com", why do you loop through all 3 OneDrive Environ variables and not just pick `"OneDriveCommercial"`/`"OneDrive"` for sharepoint style links and `"OneDriveConsumer"`/`"OneDrive"` for other links

Answer (score 2):

Hallo this is how I do it, I found my the path through "SOFTWARE\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive":

```
private static string GetLocalPath(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            var oneDriveKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive");

            if (oneDriveKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var subKeyName in oneDriveKey.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    var subKey = oneDriveKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);

                    if (subKey != null)
                    {
                        var urlNameSpace = subKey.GetValue("UrlNamespace").ToString().Trim('/');

                        if (url.Contains(urlNameSpace) && subKey.GetValue("MountPoint") is string localLibraryPath)
                        {
                            string restOfDocumentPath = url.Substring(urlNameSpace.Length);
                            restOfDocumentPath = restOfDocumentPath.Replace('/', '\\');

                            return localLibraryPath + restOfDocumentPath;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small improvement on Philip Swannell's improvement of Virtuoso's original answer for when the number of "\" to remove from the path is more than 4 / varies (depending on the file, i found i needed to remove 5 or sometimes 6 of these). The shortcomings mentioned by Philip are still there though.

```
Private Function Local_Workbook_Name(ByRef wb As Workbook) As String
'returns local wb path or nothing if local path not found
    Dim i As Long
    Dim OneDrivePath As String
    Dim ShortName As String
    Dim testWbkPath As String
    Dim OneDrivePathFound As Boolean

    'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
    If InStr(1, wb.FullName, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Replace forward slashes with back slashes
        ShortName = Replace(wb.FullName, "/", "\")

        'Remove the first four backslashes
        For i = 1 To 4
            ShortName = RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ShortName)
        Next

        'loop through three OneDrive options
        For i = 1 To 3
            OneDrivePath = Environ(Choose(i, "OneDrive", "OneDriveCommercial", "OneDriveConsumer"))
            If Len(OneDrivePath) > 0 Then
                'Loop to see if the tentative LocalWorkbookName is the name of a file that actually exists, if so return the name
                Do While ShortName Like "*\*"
                    testWbkPath = OneDrivePath & "\" & ShortName
                    If Not (Dir(testWbkPath)) = vbNullString Then
                        OneDrivePathFound = True
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    'remove top folder in path
                    ShortName = RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ShortName)
                Loop
            End If
            If OneDrivePathFound Then Exit For
        Next i
    Else
        Local_Workbook_Name = wb.FullName
    End If

    If OneDrivePathFound Then Local_Workbook_Name = testWbkPath

End Function
Function RemoveTopFolderFromPath(ByVal ShortName As String) As String
    RemoveTopFolderFromPath = Mid(ShortName, InStr(ShortName, "\") + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Call me a hacker but the http reference on my machine is always the same so I looked at the local reference on my hard drive where the OneDrive could be found

Lets say that was `C:\MyOneDrive\OneDrive` then took all the other parts of the workbook path that weren't needed and added on the local part. Then switched the slash direction

```
folder = "C:\MyOneDrive\OneDrive" & Right(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, Len(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path) - 72) & "\"
folder = Replace(folder, "/", "\")
```

My two lines covered all the cases on my machine!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem be creating a symbolic link (mklink /d). Opening files through a desktop shortcut to the link meant that WB.FullName always returned the file path using the symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

As you all seem to work on Windows-System you can also use the filescripting object:

```
Debug.Print
Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.Path:     "; ThisWorkbook.Path
Debug.Print "ThisWorkbook.FullName: "; ThisWorkbook.FullName
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Debug.Print "Scripting.fso:         "; .GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
End With
```

Comment: objFSO.FileExists(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)) returns false. Does not work

Answer (score -1):

I solved this without VBA.
Instead I used [Power Query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_BI#History).

First I use this formula in a cell, to get the path without filename and worksheetname:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename";E8);FIND("[";CELL("filename";E8))-1)
```

Then I import the path as a table in Power Query: "Råfilsti"

I then have another query that has this as its source. Here I do some datawrangling on the HTTPS file path. I hard coded my local [OneDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive) path in the query, but you can copy paste your OneDrive root folder into a cell in Excel and call that as a parameter to use in Power Query.

[image]

Then load that query into a table in the workbook.

Comment: Hello, [please don't add your code as an image!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12287457). Regarding your code: Having to hard-code/manually supply one's OneDrive folder, in my opinion, undermines this solution's usefulness because in this case, you might as well hard-code//manually supply the entire local path. Also, you are assuming many things in this solution that will not always be true, for example, that the URL contains the word "Documents". As a result, this solution will find the wrong local path in many cases.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75084360/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.