# ThisWorkbook.FullName returns a URL after syncing with OneDrive. I want the file path on disk

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a workbook on OneDrive. Usually, ThisWorkbook.FullName returns a path on disk:

```
c:\Users\MyName\OneDrive - MyCompany\BlaBla\MyWorkbook 09-21-17.xlsb
```

But after a set of operation in VBA where I manually save the file to a backup folder and rename the current file with a new date, OneDrive syncs and ThisWorkbook.FullName returns a URL:

```
https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/personal/MyName_Company_com/Documents/mycompany/Apps/BlaBla/MyWorkbook 10-21-17.xlsb
```

I need the path to disk, even when ThisWorkbook.FullName returns a URL.

If I wanted to hack something together, I could save the path before my operations, but I want to be able to retrieve the disk path at any time.

I've seen some procedures other people have hacked together, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive), but it more or less just reformats the URL into a path on disk. Doing this isn't reliable as the URL path and the disk path don't always have the same directory structure (see the reformatting done in the linked procedure compared to the directory structures I give as examples above).

Is there a solid, direct, way of returning the path on disk of the Workbook, even if it's syncing online and ThisWorkbook.FullName is returning a URL?

Comment: Pretty sure that "hack" you linked to is the only way. `ThisWorkbook.FullName` returns what it returns.

Comment: What's `CurDir` returning before & after the sync?

Comment: "C:\Users\MyName\Documents"

Edit: Both before and after the sync.

Comment: A logical next step from that would be to remove "Documents" from that string and add on the OneDrive folder, however, that OneDrive folder name can be different for different people depending on how it's been shared to them.

Comment: @RMK, you might want to check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457). I also answered in [your thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736800/12287457), but I will keep my main answer on the other thread because it is older and has more views/upvotes/answers, in short, exposure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution for this problem. The assignment of Sharepoint libraries to local mountpoints is stored in the registry, the following function will convert the URL to a local filename. I edited this to incorporate RMK's suggestions:

```
Function GetLocalFile(wb As Workbook) As String
    ' Set default return
    GetLocalFile = wb.FullName

    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

    Dim strValue As String

    Dim objReg As Object: Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    Dim strRegPath As String: strRegPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    Dim arrSubKeys() As Variant
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath, arrSubKeys

    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In arrSubKeys
        ' check if this key has a value named "UrlNamespace", and save the value to strValue
        objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "UrlNamespace", strValue

        ' If the namespace is in FullName, then we know we have a URL and need to get the path on disk
        If InStr(wb.FullName, strValue) > 0 Then
            Dim strTemp As String
            Dim strCID As String
            Dim strMountpoint As String
        
            ' Get the mount point for OneDrive
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "MountPoint", strMountpoint
        
            ' Get the CID
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "CID", strCID
        
            ' strip off the namespace and CID
            strTemp = Right(wb.FullName, Len(wb.FullName) - Len(strValue & "/" & strCID))
        
            ' replace all forward slashes with backslashes
            GetLocalFile = strMountpoint & Replace(strTemp, "/", "\")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I feel like we're getting close with this one. When I test it out on my home computer with the Excel file in the root OneDrive directory, I'm getting an output similar to:
"C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\\1a1234a123456abc\filename.xlsb"

It should be:
"C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\filename.xlsb"

The "1a1234a123456abc" is the CID and there appears to be an extra slash.

Comment: I got it to work. I'll mark your answer as the solution if you fix a few things. You have to pull the CID from the registry and remove it from the path. You also concatenate an unnecessary backslash. Take a look at my answer for the full code I wrote up.

Comment: Ah, the backslash is unnecessary when your file is in the onedrive's root folder, my test cases were all in subfolders of the onedrive's root folder.

Comment: Floris came across a situation where the CID returned an empty string. My code would then add a slash after the empty string, resulting in an extra slash. To resolve this, I update my code below with a couple extra lines to test for the empty string.

Answer (score 9):

This is corrected and restyled code from beerockxs. It works on my machine, but I'm not sure how well it'll work on other setups. If others could test, that would be great. I'll be marking beerockxs answer at the solution.

```
Function GetLocalFile(wb As Workbook) As String
    ' Set default return
    GetLocalFile = wb.FullName
    
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

    Dim strValue As String
    
    Dim objReg As Object: Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    Dim strRegPath As String: strRegPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    Dim arrSubKeys() As Variant
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath, arrSubKeys
    
    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In arrSubKeys
        ' check if this key has a value named "UrlNamespace", and save the value to strValue
        objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "UrlNamespace", strValue
    
        ' If the namespace is in FullName, then we know we have a URL and need to get the path on disk
        If InStr(wb.FullName, strValue) > 0 Then
            Dim strTemp As String
            Dim strCID As String
            Dim strMountpoint As String
            
            ' Get the mount point for OneDrive
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "MountPoint", strMountpoint
            
            ' Get the CID
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "CID", strCID
            
            ' Add a slash, if the CID returned something
            If strCID <> vbNullString Then
                strCID = "/" & strCID
            End If

            ' strip off the namespace and CID
            strTemp = Right(wb.FullName, Len(wb.FullName) - Len(strValue & strCID))
            
            ' replace all forward slashes with backslashes
            GetLocalFile = strMountpoint & Replace(strTemp, "/", "\")
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Great solution RMK, thank you, it really helped me out. I had to make one change - the string strCID is empty on my system, which results in *Len(strValue & "/" & strCID)* having one character too many (it ends in two slashes). The variable strTemp therefore returns 'ocuments/..' in stead of 'Documents/..' for me. I added an if-else to the definition of strTemp to solve this.

Comment: Thank you, Floris! I updated my code to account for that.

Comment: Please give this answer more credit, it's the only solution that solves the problem in a reliable way. Similar answers in other threads completely missed out on getting URL + local path pairs from the registry and provided only the local ones.

Comment: Yes, great solution. I suggest adding (after the third line) the line:
`If Instr(GetLocalFile,"https://") = 0 Then Exit function`
which speeds things up if in fact the file is not on OneDrive at all.

Comment: Thanks RMK - this was a massive help. I had to make just a few minor tweaks; see the Answer I just posted.

Answer (score 5):

```
Sub get_folder_path()

'early binding
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

'late binding
'Dim fso As Object
'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As String
folder = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
Debug.Print (folder)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.  Most elegant solution to this problem I've seen so far.

Comment: At first I thought this worked, but it doesn't seem to give the correct path on disk. Honestly, all it seems to do is prepend  "c:\Users\MyName\Documents" to whatever you give it.

Comment: Good use of FSO object.  Now all I need to do is trim/remove the file-name to get just the folder path.

Comment: I confirm @RMK comment.  It returns "c:\Users\MyName\Documents\MyFile.xlsm" while correct fullpath is "c:\Users\MyName\Documents\auto\MyFile.xlsm"

Comment: fso.GetAbsolutePathName(ThisWorkbook.Name) just returns CurDir & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name.  In fact, if you ChDir before it, it uses the new changed CurDir.

Answer (score 5):

## EDIT:

This answer is now outdated and the conclusions from this post are incomplete. Please look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) instead!

---

I have now looked through a bunch of solutions for this problem on the web, including various StackOverflow threads and none of them work for all the different kinds of OneDrive folders/accounts.

Here is a short summary of my tests of the solutions in this thread:

@RMK's solution only works for the *personal* OneDrive folder

@beerockxs's solution also only works for the *personal* OneDrive folder

@Danny's solution only works in very rare cases, for me it never worked

@Henrik Bøgelund's solution didn't work

@Erik van der Neut's solution worked in most cases, but in case of a private OneDrive it introduced one extra `"\"` into the path. This can easily be fixed, but also, it doesn't work if the synchronized folder is not at the base of the folder hierarchy in the online file structure. In that case, extra path parts exist in the WebPath which are carried into the local path making it invalid.

The following function will work in most cases, for a universal solution, please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

```vb
Public Function GetLocalPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    Const HKCU = &H80000001
    Dim objReg As Object, rPath As String, subKeys(), subKey
    Dim urlNamespace As String, mountPoint As String, secPart As String
    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\." & _
                           "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    rPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    objReg.EnumKey HKCU, rPath, subKeys
    For Each subKey In subKeys
        objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "UrlNamespace", urlNamespace
        If InStr(Path, urlNamespace) > 0 Then
            objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "MountPoint", mountPoint
            secPart = Replace(Mid(Path, Len(urlNamespace)), "/", "\")
            Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Do Until Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Or InStr(2, secPart, "\") = 0
                secPart = Mid(secPart, InStr(2, secPart, "\"))
                Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetLocalPath = Path
End Function
```

Comment: Working for me, correctly converting "https://d.docs.live.net/e06a[etc...]/Documenti/MyFolder/MyFile.xlsm" to "C:\Users\myUserName\OneDrive\Documenti\MyFolder\MyFile.xlsm".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used Windows a environment variable to solve this problem.

In my example I was using a private OneDrive, but it is fairly simple to change the code to handle OneDrive for Business. The environment variable would then be "OneDriveCommercial" instead of "OneDriveConsumer".

This is my code for converting the OneDrive URL into a local path:

```
Rem consumer URL to OneDrive root: "https://d.docs.live.net/<64-bit hex value>/"
OneDriveServerURL = "https://d.docs.live.net/"

path = ActiveWorkbook.path
Worksheets("Menu").Range("G6").Value = path

If Left(path, Len(OneDriveServerURL)) = OneDriveServerURL Then
  Rem remove from start to first "/" after server URL
  path = Mid(path, InStr(Len(OneDriveServerURL) + 1, path, "/"))

  Rem replce "/" by "\"
  path = Replace(path, "/", Application.PathSeparator)

  Rem add OneDrive root folder from environment variable
  path = Environ("OneDriveConsumer") + path
End If
```

Comment: Neither Environ("OneDriveConsumer") or Environ("OneDriveCommercial") return anything for me in the Immediate Window.

Comment: Try this: --  
1. Open a command prompt. (press windows key and type cmd)  --  
2. Enter the command: "set"  --  
3. Press enter  --  
It should now list all your environment variables.
On my Windows machine I have the two variables mentioned above - but perhaps your implementation is different, and uses a third name for the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a personal OneDrive, use Environ("OneDriveConsumer")

The code:
Environ("OneDriveCommercial")+Replace(Right(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - (InStr(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "/Documents/") + 9)),"/","")

"/Documents/" should be standard, but your OneDrive may have a different setup. If so, you will need to replace "/Documents/" (the end of the OneDrive Prefix) with whatever you have. and replace the "9" to be the length of what you have minus 2.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Do you miss a \ at the end of line? Environ("OneDriveCommercial")+Replace(Right(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName) - (InStr(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "/Documents/") + 9)),"/","\")

Answer (score 0):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/online-path-returned-rather-than-local-path/2ea9970d-383b-4893-afab-38041fee65fe

This did the trick for me. No extra code

Open the OneDrive app settings > go to the Office tab > untick "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open", then reopen your workbook

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to do SaveAs, **there's literally a Parameter called "Local"** that will cause all properties (FullName/Path/etc.) to resolve based on the language of the local machine.

**Just add "Local:=True" to the SaveAs call** and you'll be good to go.

So in my case I use:

```
Sub ExportCurrentWorkbook()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 ws.Copy

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv", xlCSVUTF8, _
 ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Local:=True

 ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

MSDN Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to beerockxs and RMK for their excellent responses.

I had to make a few minor adjustments to get it to work reliably. For example, in my case a CID value was returned, but the CID was not actually part of the full OneDrive URL. So, because of that, stripping off the number of characters for that broke the local path for me.

As a solution, I'm not stripping off the CID and URL Name Space by counting characters, but instead by doing simple String Replace operations. That way, if you get a CID value back that is not part of the URL, it won't remove anything from the URL for that. It also makes the code a little easier to read.

In my case I need the local root folder of my Excel spreadsheet, so created a simple extra method on top of that as well.

I also added a few simple Mac checks (to avoid this from trying to run on a Mac, as it won't work for that), and added some debug MsgBox calls -- comment those out once you find it works for you as well:

```
Function GetLocalPath(wb As Workbook) As String

    strLocalFile = GetLocalFile(wb)
    
    ' Remove everything after the last slash to get just the path itself:
    GetLocalPath = Left(strLocalFile, InStrRev(strLocalFile, "\"))
    
    ''''''''''''''' DEBUG '''''''''''''''''''''''''
    MsgBox "Local file:" & vbCrLf & strLocalFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Local path:" & vbCrLf & GetLocalPath
    ''''''''''''''' DEBUG '''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Function


Function GetLocalFile(wb As Workbook) As String
#If Mac Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, this script only works on Windows."
#Else
    ' Set default return
    GetLocalFile = wb.FullName
    
    Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

    Dim strUrlNameSpace As String
    
    Dim objReg As Object: Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    Dim strRegPath As String: strRegPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    Dim arrSubKeys() As Variant
    objReg.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath, arrSubKeys
    
    Dim varKey As Variant
    For Each varKey In arrSubKeys
        ' Check if this key has a value named "UrlNamespace", and save the value to strUrlNameSpace:
        objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "UrlNamespace", strUrlNameSpace
        
        ' If the namespace is in FullName, then we know we have a URL and need to get the path on disk:
        If InStr(wb.FullName, strUrlNameSpace) > 0 Then
            Dim strTemp As String
            Dim strCID As String
            Dim strMountpoint As String
            
            ' Get the mount point for OneDrive, and make sure it ends in "\":
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "MountPoint", strMountpoint
            If Right(strMountpoint, 1) <> "\" Then
                strMountpoint = strMountpoint & "\"
            End If
            
            ' Get the CID, and add "/" at the start if any value returned:
            objReg.getStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strRegPath & varKey, "CID", strCID
            If strCID <> vbNullString Then
                strCID = "/" & strCID
            End If

            ' Replace the URL name space with local mount point:
            strTemp = Replace(wb.FullName, strUrlNameSpace, strMountpoint)
            
            ' Remove CID from the path if the CID is indeed part of it:
            strTemp = Replace(strTemp, strCID, "")
            
            ' Replace any remaining forward slashes with backslashes:
            GetLocalFile = Replace(strTemp, "/", "\")
            
            ''''''''''''''' DEBUG '''''''''''''''''''''''''
            MsgBox "OneDrive URL:" & vbCrLf & wb.FullName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "URL Name Space (strUrlNameSpace):" & vbCrLf & strUrlNameSpace & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "OneDrive Mount Point (strMountpoint):" & vbCrLf & strMountpoint & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "CID (strCID):" & vbCrLf & strCID & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Local file:" & vbCrLf & GetLocalFile
            ''''''''''''''' DEBUG '''''''''''''''''''''''''
            
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
#End If
End Function
```

Verified in testing that this now works perfectly, both in OneDrive folders and in regular folders.

Erik