# Write xml from VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I've written a VBA script that inserts data from an Excel workbook into an xml-file.
The xml-file to be edited is chosen from a filedialogpicker:

```
Public strFile As String
    
Sub SetPath()

' Declare filedialog picker
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

' Define attributes for the filepicker to only allow a single xml file
With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "XML files", "*.xml", 1
    .Title = "Choose file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    ' If a file is chosen save the path and name
    If .Show = True Then
    
        strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    
    Else
        
        'MsgBox "Error"
    
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

After which I open, edit and save the file:

```
Sub WriteXML()
   
Call SetPath

' Open the xml-file
Dim xmlFile As String
xmlFile = strFile
     
Set xmlWriter = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlWriter.async = False
xmlWriter.Load xmlFile
    
' long codeblock for editing the file
    
xmlWriter.Save xmlFile
Set xmlWriter = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The code works fine on my private computer, however running it on my company PC I get the error:
"the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

I suspect that it involves my company pc using sharepoint thus making the save path:

'https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mat_company_com/Documents/Desktop/myTemplates/Templates/file.xml'

As opposed to:
'C:\Users\Mat\Documents\file.xml'

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The filename is too long.

Comment: @jdweng - the URL is only 104 characters without "file" - so the filename would have to be 296 chars long for the whole URL to be too long. This isn't the issue

Comment: Is it the line `xmlWriter.Save xmlFile` that throws the error? Or the `.Show` or the `.SelectedItems(1)`?

Comment: Try a shorter file path.  Seen issue with longer than 64.  Or use File Explorer and see if you can create a file in the folder.  You may not have permission.   A sharepoint is not a file system.  It uses a different protocol.  See with File Explorer is you can get to folder.

Comment: Yes, it is the line `xmlWriter.Save xmlFile` that throws the error.
Unfortunately my company pc uses the Sharepoint file path by default if I run the `SetPath()` sub. I've tried formatting the path to resemble that of my private pc but this results in an error stating that it is unable to find the specified file.

Comment: HTTP locations and filesystem locations are quite different things, and what works for local/network locations typically is going to fail when you're working with a HTTP location.  If you can sync the folder of interest then you can work with your local copy and any changes will get synced up to SharePoint.

Comment: How can I accomplish this from VBA? The Excel-file as well as the xml file are both located and my PC synchronies automatically with sharepoint.

Comment: If the source SharePoint location is synced to your local PC then the content will be on your local drive somewhere like: `C:\Users\Mathias\YourSharePointHost\SyncedFoldeRnameHere`

Comment: ...if ActiveWorkbook was opened from SharePoint then it's going to have an HTTP path - there are ways to convert that to the matching local path if the source has been synced.  Eg see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697487/478884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need Mac support, this shows how to convert an HTTP path to a local path, assuming the SharePoint source is synced to your local drive:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim p As String
    
    p = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    If UCase(p) Like "HTTP*" Then p = GetLocalPath(p)
    
    Debug.Print "Local Path is:", vbLf, p

End Sub

'See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67697487/478884
Public Function GetLocalPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    Const HKCU = &H80000001
    Dim objReg As Object, rPath As String, subKeys(), subKey
    Dim urlNamespace As String, mountPoint As String, secPart As String
    
    Debug.Print "Checking for:" & vbLf & Path
    Debug.Print "--------------------"
    
    Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\." & _
                           "\root\default:StdRegProv")
    rPath = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"
    objReg.EnumKey HKCU, rPath, subKeys
    For Each subKey In subKeys
        
        objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "UrlNamespace", urlNamespace
        Debug.Print urlNamespace
        
        If InStr(1, Path, urlNamespace, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            objReg.GetStringValue HKCU, rPath & subKey, "MountPoint", mountPoint
            secPart = Replace(Mid(Path, Len(urlNamespace)), "/", "\")
            Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Do Until Dir(Path, vbDirectory) <> "" Or InStr(2, secPart, "\") = 0
                secPart = Mid(secPart, InStr(2, secPart, "\"))
                Path = mountPoint & secPart
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetLocalPath = Path
End Function
```