# How to get the current directory in Excel when file on a cloud?

Tags: excel, path, directory

I have an excel spreadsheet that needs to get the current directory of the file.  For a worksheet function I use =LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1), in VBA I use ActiveWorkbook.Path.  The file is on my hard drive in my OneDrive folder so it is synced to the cloud.  Sometimes I have no issues (most of the time), but at times the file directory will be the cloud path (htpps://....) and this will not work.

Does anyone know how to always get the local path?

Comment: You could check if the path is a url (starts with http) If your file is in the cloud, I doubt that your provider allows it and even that it makes sense..

Comment: yes, i could check that, but I still need the local directory.

Comment: You can convert the cloud path (url) to a local path using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).

Answer (score 0):

The `=INFO("Directory")` formula might be able to help with this:

[image]

I haven't tried it with One Drive, but the formula seems simpler and less likely to error.

Source: https://gridmaster.io/spreadsheet-tips/show-file-path-excel