# Excel file synced from OneDrive showing online filepath, not local

Tags: excel, onedrive

This just started this morning. I run power queries on my files, so I need an absolute local path. For ease, I have a cell with =CELL("filename",A1) to provide said local path, from which I can run the relevant queries. Today, they all broke. The filepath is showing the online path (https://xxxx-my.sharepout.com/personal/...) rather than the local file path.
I thought it might be an issue with where the file is stored, so I went to the OneDrive folder on my computer and set everything to "Always store on this device" then let everything download, but it's still pulling through the online path, rather than the local.
How can I get it back to local path so the Queries can work?

Comment: Try opening OneDrive folder from the start menu and then reopen the workbook.

Comment: Following the file path and then opening the workbook doesn't help. Is there a setting or something I may have clicked that asks it to always use the online version? Even creating a new workbook in the folder (from Windows Explorer) and checking the filepath of that new file shows the online path.

Comment: You can convert the online path to a local path using the function shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457). You can use this function in macros directly or just as a user-defined function directly from the cells of your worksheet. Just paste the function into a standard code module in the VBA IDE and save your workbook as ".xlsm" so the macros get saved with it. Then you can convert any online path into a local path like this: `=GetLocalPath("online path")`

Answer (score 0):

Reading discussions of similar problems on some Microsoft support site suggests that this is by design. One **workaround** that I've seen discussed is to go into your OneDrive settings and disable "Use Office applications to sync Office files that I open".  I think this will work BUT there is a downside (TANSTAAFL).

As I understand it, with this disabled, you are no longer guaranteed that the document is being updated if someone else modifies that file and there may be problems merging changes made in multiple places. I've not seen any good discussion of the negatives although the "More info" link in the settings might be helpful to others (they don't help me much).

[image: Screenshot of OneDrive File collaboration setting]