# vba excel does not find files and folders in sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

Macro in PathTest.xlsm:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    Range("A3").Value = Path

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Range("A4").Value = fso.FolderExists(Path)                    ' False!
    Range("A5").Value = fso.FileExists(Path + "\PathTest.xlsm")   ' False!
End Sub
```

This code works if file is stored in any normal folder, but when placed in Onedrive folder the check for existance fails.

Any hints?
/Peter

Comment: What does `Path` look like?  FSO may be unable to scan an HTTP path for example.

Comment: This will work if you use the function from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) to convert the path returned by `ActiveWorkbook.Path`. So copy the function from the linked post and use `Path = GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.Path)`