# Open an Access database on OneDrive using Excel-VBA and ADODB conecction

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, onedrive, adodb

I need to open an Access DB on OneDrive using Excel-VBA and ADODB connection or SQL. Until a month ago the object `ThisWorkBook.Path` give me the local path of the file store on OneDrive, nevertheless now I get an http with this object.

Comment: This probably means that you haven't opened the file from your local store. Please include in your question how you opened the workbook (and from which path you opened it). Also include what the http url is you get from `ThisWorkbook.Path`. Maybe [mcve] can help to improve your question.

Comment: If you have the Workbook in a locally synced OneDrive folder, you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) to convert the output of `ThisWorkbook.Path` to the local path.

Answer (score 0):

I uses the follow macro to find local file.

```
'This Function search root folder as C: ,D: ...
'Search into all OneDrive folders
Option Explicit
Private Const strProtocol   As String = "Http"
Private Const pathSeparator As String = "\"

Function MainFindFile(ByRef NullFilePath As String, Optional FileName As String) As Boolean
    
    Dim fso                 As FileSystemObject 'Necessary enable microsoft scripting runtime in references
    Dim UserRootFolder      As Folder
    Dim SecondSubFolders    As Folder
    Dim ThirdSubFolders     As Folder
    Dim InitialPath         As String
    Dim OneDriveFolderName  As String
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    InitialPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    If FileName = vbNullString Then FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    If InStr(1, InitialPath, strProtocol, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        InitialPath = Environ("SystemDrive")
        InitialPath = InitialPath & Environ("HomePath")
        
        'Gets all folders in user root folder
        Set UserRootFolder = fso.GetFolder(InitialPath)
        
        For Each SecondSubFolders In UserRootFolder.SubFolders
            'Searches all folders of OneDrive, you may have how many Onedrive's folders as you want
            If InStr(1, SecondSubFolders.Name, "OneDrive", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                OneDriveFolderName = InitialPath & pathSeparator & SecondSubFolders.Name
                'Verifies if file exists in root of Onedrive Folder
                MainFindFile = SearchFile(OneDriveFolderName, FileName, NullFilePath)
                If MainFindFile Then Exit For

                'Uses recursive function to percur all subfolders in root of OneDrive
                For Each ThirdSubFolders In fso.GetFolder(OneDriveFolderName).SubFolders
                    MainFindFile = RecursiveFindFile(ThirdSubFolders, FileName, NullFilePath)
                    If MainFindFile Then Exit For
                Next ThirdSubFolders
            End If
            If MainFindFile Then Exit For
        Next SecondSubFolders
        
    End If
    
    MsgBox NullFilePath
    
End Function
Private Function RecursiveFindFile(Folder As Folder, FileName As String, ByRef NullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim fso         As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder   As Folder
    Dim Result      As Boolean
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    'Verifies if file exists in root of Onedrive Folder
    RecursiveFindFile = SearchFile(Folder.Path, FileName, NullFilePath)
    If RecursiveFindFile Then Exit Function
    
    For Each objFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        If Not SearchFile(objFolder.Path, FileName, NullFilePath) Then
            RecursiveFindFile = RecursiveFindFile(objFolder, FileName, NullFilePath)
            If RecursiveFindFile Then Exit For
        Else
            RecursiveFindFile = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next objFolder
    
End Function
Private Function SearchFile(Path As String, FileName As String, ByRef NullFilePath As String) As Boolean
    
    'NullFilePath is a byref variable to be filled by this function
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    If fso.FileExists(Path & pathSeparator & FileName) Then
        NullFilePath = Path & pathSeparator & FileName
        SearchFile = True
    End If
    
End Function
```