# Why has this audit logger VBA code stopped working?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code that I copied from (https://datapluscode.com/general/add-an-audit-trail-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-vba) to record a logfile of changes in excel files that are used to collect data for clinical research.

This worked brilliantly until earlier this year when something (perhaps an update to Excel) has bricked it. It no longer records anything, although the code seems to run without obvious error.

There are two facets to the code.

Firstly, a class module called csLogger

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Type udtLogEntry
    Date            As String * 22
    NewCellValue    As String * 30
    OldCellValue    As String * 30
    CellRef         As String * 15
    UserName        As String * 10
    SheetName       As String * 20
    NewFormula      As String * 40
    OldFormula      As String * 40
    ChangeType      As String * 12
End Type

Private mudtEntry                           As udtLogEntry
Private Const CSTR_CELL_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE     As String = "Cell"
Private Const CSTR_LOG_FILENAME_SUFFIX      As String = "_log.txt"

Public Sub LogSheetChangeEvent(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER:
    Dim strText As String

    If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        If (Target.Rows.Count = 1) And (Target.Columns.Count = 1) Then
            mudtEntry.SheetName = CStr(Sh.Name)
            mudtEntry.CellRef = CStr(Target.Address)
            mudtEntry.ChangeType = CSTR_CELL_ADJUSTMENT_TYPE
            mudtEntry.Date = CStr(Now())
            mudtEntry.NewCellValue = CStr(Target.Value)
            mudtEntry.UserName = Environ("username")
            mudtEntry.NewFormula = CStr(Target.Formula)
            strText = BuildLogString(mudtEntry.Date, mudtEntry.NewCellValue, _
                                     mudtEntry.OldCellValue, mudtEntry.CellRef, _
                                     mudtEntry.UserName, mudtEntry.SheetName, mudtEntry.OldFormula, _
                                     mudtEntry.NewFormula, mudtEntry.ChangeType)
            Call fnAddToFile(strText)
        End If
    End If
EXIT_HERE:
    Exit Sub
ERR_HANDLER:
    GoTo EXIT_HERE
End Sub

Public Sub LogSheetSelectionChangeEvent(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        If (Target.Rows.Count = 1) And (Target.Columns.Count = 1) Then
             mudtEntry.OldCellValue = CStr(Target.Value)
             mudtEntry.OldFormula = CStr(Target.Formula)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub LogEventAction(ByVal strEvent As String)
    Dim udtEntry As udtLogEntry
    udtEntry.Date = Now()
    udtEntry.ChangeType = strEvent
    udtEntry.UserName = Environ("username")
    If Not fnAddToFile(udtEntry.Date & "," & udtEntry.UserName & "," & udtEntry.ChangeType) Then
        Debug.Print "Failed to log event"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function fnAddToFile(ByVal strText As String) As Boolean
    
On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER:
    Dim intHandle   As Integer
    Dim strFileName As String
    
    fnAddToFile = False
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        fnAddToFile = False
        GoTo EXIT_HERE
    End If
    
    intHandle = FreeFile
    strFileName = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 1, InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
    strFileName = strFileName & CSTR_LOG_FILENAME_SUFFIX
    strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Chr(92) & strFileName
    
    If Not IsLogFilePresent(strFileName) Then
        Open strFileName For Append As #intHandle
            Dim udtHeader As udtLogEntry
            Dim strTitles As String
            
            udtHeader.SheetName = "Sheet Name"
            udtHeader.Date = "Date & Time"
            udtHeader.CellRef = "Cell Ref"
            udtHeader.SheetName = "Sheetname"
            udtHeader.UserName = "UserName"
            udtHeader.NewCellValue = "New Value"
            udtHeader.OldCellValue = "Old Value"
            udtHeader.NewFormula = "New Value Formula"
            udtHeader.OldFormula = "Old Value Formula"
            udtHeader.ChangeType = "Type"
            
            strTitles = BuildLogString(udtHeader.Date, udtHeader.NewCellValue, _
                                       udtHeader.OldCellValue, udtHeader.CellRef, _
                                       udtHeader.UserName, udtHeader.SheetName, _
                                       udtHeader.OldFormula, udtHeader.NewFormula, _
                                       udtHeader.ChangeType)
            Print #intHandle, strTitles
            Print #intHandle, strText
        Close #intHandle
    Else
        Open strFileName For Append As #intHandle
            Print #intHandle, strText
        Close #intHandle
    End If

    fnAddToFile = True
EXIT_HERE:
    Exit Function
ERR_HANDLER:
    fnAddToFile = False
    GoTo EXIT_HERE
End Function

Private Function BuildLogString(ByVal strDate As String, ByVal strNew As String, ByVal strOld As String, _
                                ByVal strRef As String, ByVal strName As String, ByVal strSheet As String, _
                                ByVal strOldFormula As String, ByVal strNewFormula As String, ByVal strChangeType As String) As String
    Dim strText As String
    On Error Resume Next
    strSheet = UCase(strSheet)
    BuildLogString = _
           strDate & "," & strName & "," & strChangeType & "," & strSheet & "," & strRef & ", " & strNew & "," & strOld & _
               "," & strNewFormula & "," & strOldFormula
End Function

Private Function IsLogFilePresent(ByVal strFile As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER:
    IsLogFilePresent = False
    If Trim(Dir(strFile)) <> "" Then
        IsLogFilePresent = True
    Else
        IsLogFilePresent = False
    End If
EXIT_HERE:
    Exit Function
ERR_HANDLER:
    IsLogFilePresent = False
    GoTo EXIT_HERE
End Function
```

Then, code in ThisWorkbook, as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private mObjLogger As csLogger

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not mObjLogger Is Nothing Then
        mObjLogger.LogEventAction ("CLOSE")
        Set mObjLogger = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    If Not mObjLogger Is Nothing Then
        mObjLogger.LogEventAction ("SAVE")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Set mObjLogger = New csLogger
    mObjLogger.LogEventAction ("OPEN")
    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not mObjLogger Is Nothing Then
        mObjLogger.LogSheetChangeEvent Sh, Target
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not mObjLogger Is Nothing Then
        mObjLogger.LogSheetSelectionChangeEvent Sh, Target
    End If
End Sub
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why it is no longer working I would be really grateful! I cannot work it out. I tried to ask on the original page but my comments are rejected by the server. The author also no longer seems to be active. Thank you.

Comment: Try commenting out all of the error handlers and see what happens.

Comment: If you enter `? ThisWorkbook.Name` into the Immediate pane and press enter what do you get?

Comment: I don't know how to comment out all of the error handlers. I'm pretty green to all this and have no specific training. Trying to do a research study on a shoestring!

Comment: Print ThisWorkbook.Name
schedule_of_assessments_VBA_protected_IRAS_submission_v115_b.xlsm

Comment: Put a single quote in front of every line like `On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER:` (ie. comment it out)

Comment: Did you move to Office 365?  Are you using SharePoint/OneDrive for file storage?

Comment: Oh I see. I'll try that.

Comment: Yes I am using OneDrive for this. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You're absolutely right - it is OneDrive causing the problem

Comment: How infuriating!

Comment: Thank you so much. You've saved me so much stress. I will reconfigure the files so we don't rely on OneDrive

Comment: OneDrive uses `https://...` paths, which Dir() and other file-related pieces of the code can't deal with.

Comment: FYI if you're using OneDrive then typically there's a corresponding "local" drive location.  You can use the accepted answer here to map to that location:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive