# How can a VBA reference be added permanently to a Microsoft Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Microsoft Excel workbooks with formulas using a function defined in a common workbook with the project name **Makron**.

**PROBLEM**: Whenever I open one of the workbooks, it fails to calculate cell values because it does not find the function. I have to press Alt+F11, go to The Tools menu, select Preferences... and check the box in front of **Makron**:

[image: screenshot of references]

Then I press OK, close Visual Basic for Applications, press F9 to recalculate the cell values, and save the workbook.

It behaves the same whether it is normal workbook or saved as a macro-enabled workbook.

**How can the reference be saved?**

Comment: After checking the box next to Makron do you save the project?

Comment: Yes @freeflow, I save the workbook when I close it (edited question to mention it).

Comment: [Missing References In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this will work since I've not added an xslm as a reference in VBA before, but if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69929593/2221001) is accurate, then instead of a reference you may just be able to open the `xslm` file on `Workbook_Open()` and have it all behave the same as if you added through `Tools>References`, kind of like late-binding it, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @JNevill, I added the following macro to one of the workbooks:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Makron.xlsm"
End Sub
```

Now the checkbox in front of Makron is still checked when I start Excel and open the workbook, so the formulas using the function work! Not sure why it helped because when I tested before, I kept Makron.xlsm open when I closed and opened the workbook that uses the function.

So the solution might be to add this code to each workbook that needs something from Makron.xlsm. I will edit this answer if the solution stops working or a simpler solution is found.

Comment: Might be a better idea to use a [personal workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790) or an add-in.

Comment: @BigBen Is it possible to have several such personal workbooks? I already have one for other things. Now I want to create macros for a particular set of workbooks in a folder.

Comment: I'd recommend an add-in (.xlam) for that use case

Comment: If you don't want to get into .xlams, you can have as many personal workbooks as you like, just put them in the same folder - by default it is C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART. There is also an advanced option "At startup, open all files in:" and you can choose any folder.