# Excel VBA filename error after conversion to onedrive

Tags: excel, vba

Noob looking for help with a macro someone else made for me.
The macro pulls in a file converts it to another format and saves as a new file. Our users are converting over to OneDrive, so now the filename errors out when I add the new name, saying it can not find it.

Sub Macro1()

```
ChDir "\\domain.local\data\Users\katie\Documents\ScheduleReports"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "\\domain.local\data\Users\katie\Documents\ScheduleReports\Crew Schedule.csv"

Worksheets("Crew Schedule").Activate
```

I tried to change the file location to:

Sub Macro1()

```
ChDir "C:\Users\katie\OneDrive - Company\Documents\ScheduleReports"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\katie\OneDrive - Company\Documents\ScheduleReports\Crew Schedule.csv"

Worksheets("Crew Schedule").Activate
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this link help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive

Comment: You can remove `ChDir ` as it's not doing you any favors