# VBA Document.Path returns Web path when in OneDrive - Need local path

Tags: vba, directory, path, onedrive, cpu-word

I am trying to get the local file path to an open document.
When I use the Path function I get a web path if the document is in my OneDrive folder.
I think the problem is that the file exists in 2 places:
C:\Users\myloginname\OneDrive\Documents\Project\Samples
AND
https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/Documents/Project/Samples

When I try to use the Dir function with the web "path" I get error 52 "Bad file name or number".

How can I get the local path?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive

Comment: Thank you Tim. What a thread! In my opinion this is a missing property of the Document object. All the suggested solutions are ugly workarounds. (but I'll use one I'm sure)

Comment: From the perspective of someone who's supporting a lot of excel macros for a bunch of people slowly migrating files to Sharepoint it's definitely a headache...

Comment: @mohnston, you might be interested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will return the local name of a FullName given to it as argument.

```
Function LocalFullName(ByVal Ffn As String) As String
    ' 294

    ' this is part of the URL address before the file's code name
    ' e.g. https://d.docs.live.net/2abce27df5c02e2f/ ....
    Const DriveID   As String = ".live.net"
    
    Dim Fun()       As String           ' function return value
    Dim n           As Integer          ' index of Fun
    Dim Sp()        As String           ' split array of Ffn
    Dim i           As Integer          ' loop counter: index of Sp
    
    Sp = Split(Ffn, "/")
    For i = 1 To UBound(Sp)
        If InStr(1, Sp(i), DriveID, vbTextCompare) Then Exit For
    Next i
    
    If i > UBound(Sp) Then
        LocalFullName = Ffn
    Else
        ReDim Fun(1 To UBound(Sp))
        For i = i + 2 To UBound(Sp)
            n = n + 1
            Fun(n) = Sp(i)
        Next i
        ReDim Preserve Fun(1 To n)
        LocalFullName = Join(Fun, Application.PathSeparator)
    End If
End Function
```

If you need to use the name for saving the drive must be added. The snipper below shows how to call the function and add the drive letter.

```
Sub Snippet()
    ' 294
    
    Const DriveID   As String = "D:\"
    Dim Wb          As Workbook
    
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Debug.Print DriveID & LocalFullName(Wb.FullName)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this as I only wanted the folder path.
Also, it's kind of a choose-your-poison when using hard-coded text, but I worry that  ".live.net" might change. Of course, so could "\OneDrive\" so there ya go.

```
Private Function Local_Workbook_Path(ByRef doc As Document) As String

  Dim Ctr As Long
  Dim objShell As Object
  Dim UserProfilePath As String
  'Check if it looks like a OneDrive location
  If InStr(1, doc.path, "https://", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    'Replace forward slashes with back slashes
    Local_Workbook_Path = Replace(doc.path, "/", "\")

    'Get environment path using vbscript
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    UserProfilePath = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

      'Trim OneDrive designators
    For Ctr = 1 To 4
       Local_Workbook_Path = Mid(Local_Workbook_Path, InStr(Local_Workbook_Path, "\") + 1)
    Next

      'Construct the name
    Local_Workbook_Path = UserProfilePath & "\OneDrive\" & Local_Workbook_Path
    Local_Workbook_Path = Replace(Local_Workbook_Path, "%20", " ")
  Else

    Local_Workbook_Path = doc.path

  End If

End Function
```