# Words's fullname property with OneDrive

Tags: vba, ms-word, onedrive

I would like to do the same as this which was written for Excel, but in Word

[Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive)

I get Object issues using Philip Swannell's method. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you did try

Comment: ... and elaborate what you mean with *Object issues*

Comment: Have you tried to simply change the paramter `ByRef wb As Document`? That should do the trick. The rest is naming and up to you to change (eg I guess it's not very clever to name a document variable `wb`)

Comment: Please include the code you are using. Do not depend on the volunteers here to try and reproduce it to troubleshoot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457). After you copied the solution into a module, you can use `GetLocalPath(ThisDocument.FullName)` to get the local path for your document.