# Save my WB based on another workbook name in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a code which is doing following:

- Prompt to choose external workbook
- Copying all the data from that wb
- Pasting exactly 1:1 in main wb
- Close and Save from .xlsm to .xlsx but with a name of my main wb

  ```
    Sub CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2()

    'Prompt to choose your file in the chosen locatioon
    Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
    Dim FilePath As String
    Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    Application.StatusBar = "Choose older PDS Form!"

    dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
    dialogBox.Title = "Select a file"
    If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
        FilePath = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)

    'If nothing selected then MsgBox
    Else
       MsgBox "No PDS Form selected!"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Here are sheets defined which you are going to copy/paste (reference update) but to keep formatting.
    ''Sheets should be defined from right to left to have your sheets sorted from the beginning
    Dim shNames As Variant: shNames = Array("CH_or_Recipe_8", "CH_or_Recipe_7", "CH_or_Recipe_6", "CH_or_Recipe_5", "CH_or_Recipe_4", _
    "CH_or_Recipe_3", "CH_or_Recipe_2", "CH_or_Recipe_1", "Customer Details", "Instructions")

    Dim tgt As Workbook: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim src As Workbook: Set src = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long

    For Each ws In src.Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "*[1-8]" Then
            ws.Name = "CH_or_Recipe_" & Right(ws.Name, 1)
        ElseIf ws.Name = "Customer_Details" Then
            ws.Name = "Customer Details"
        ElseIf ws.Name = "OIPT Plasmalab" Then
            ws.Name = "CH_or_Recipe_1"
        ElseIf ws.Name = "AMAT" Then
            ws.Name = "CH_or_Recipe_2"

        End If
    Next

    For i = 0 To UBound(shNames)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = src.Sheets(shNames(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            tgt.Worksheets(shNames(i)).Cells.Clear
            Set rng = ws.UsedRange
            rng.Copy tgt.Worksheets(shNames(i)).Range(rng.Address)
        End If
    Next i
    src.Close False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Copy&Paste successful!"
    End Sub


    Sub SaveNoMacro()

    Dim fn As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        fn = Replace(.FullName, ".xlsm", ".xlsx")
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs fn, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    MsgBox "Saved as " & fn

   End Sub
  ```

What I just need (if possible) is to save my wb in the same name as that external wb that I am taking data from and adding date/time at the end.

Example:

*MainWB1.xlsm + ExternalWB1.xlsx >>> MainWB1.xlsx   (This is now)*

**MainWB1.xlsm + ExternalWB1.xlsx >>> ExternalWB1_today().xlsx**  (This is what I wanna)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 separate methods:

- `CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2`
- `SaveNoMacro`

The name of the source workbook is only available in the scope of the `CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2` because that's where you open and close it. So, you have 2 options:

1. Save the main workbook before exiting the scope of the `CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2` method i.e. while the name of the source book is available
2. Save the name of the source book somewhere (global variable, named range, registy, custom xml part etc.) or even return it as a result (`Function` instead of `Sub`) so that you can call the `SaveNoMacro` method at a later stage

### Save before exiting the scope

Here are 2 ways to do this:

1. Place your save code before the `src.Close False` line so that you can use the `src.Name` property i.e. combine the 2 methods into one. Not sure if you want to do this
2. Pass the name as an argument to the second method. In `CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2` replace this:

```
src.Close False
```

with this:

```
SaveNoMacro src.Name
src.Close False
```

and update `SaveNoMacro` to:

```
Sub SaveNoMacro(ByVal newName As String)
    Dim fn As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        fn = Replace(.FullName, .Name, Left(newName, InStrRev(newName, ".") - 1)) _
           & Format$(Date, "_yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs fn, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    MsgBox "Saved as " & fn
End Sub
```

### Save the name for later use

In case you don't want to run the 2 methods in a sequence then you can save the name for later use. Using a global variable is not a good idea as the state can be lost by the time you run the save method. Using a named range would work as long as you don't have your workbook protected i.e you can create a named range.

There are many options but the easiest to use is to write to registry using the built in `SaveSetting` option. Replace this:

```
src.Close False
```

with this:

```
SaveSetting "MyApp", "MySection", "NewBookName", src.Name
src.Close False
```

and update `SaveNoMacro` to:

```
Sub SaveNoMacro()
    Dim fn As String: fn = GetSetting("MyApp", "MySection", "NewBookName")
    If LenB(fn) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No name was saved", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        DeleteSetting "MyApp", "MySection", "NewBookName"
    End If
    With ThisWorkbook
        fn = Replace(.FullName, .Name, Left(fn, InStrRev(fn, ".") - 1)) _
           & Format$(Date, "_yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .SaveAs fn, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
    MsgBox "Saved as " & fn
End Sub
```

Comment: @Christian Buse Very nice approach. The second one seems fine, but one thing: it saved my file like XYZ.xlsx.2022-02-09 it cant recognize the file type...

Comment: @Mirza You are correct, apologies. It needs to be done before the extension. I've updated the code in both the examples to include date before extension

Comment: @Christian Buse Thats it. Works like a charm! Thanks for this! Appreciated!

Comment: @Christian Buse Sorry man! Just got one thing left, just realised it would be great to have it. What line of code can be used to delete input files from external on wb with macro once their are saved? So that I always have empty Macro wb without previous input data..

Comment: @Mirza Can you please rephrase the sentence "to delete input files from external on wb with macro once their are saved"? I do not understand what you mean

Comment: IF you see my code from above, it is taking all the data from external workbook, it is closing that external wb and saving the macro to xlsx output as you helped me already. That works like a charm, but every time I am opening my macro file there is previous data on it, from external wb, I would like to have data cleared on that macro file right after it is saved/closed in xlsx because of data/security issues. I would say something with clear.activesheet or something...

Comment: @Mirza I still don't get it. When you run ```.SaveAs``` that should save as a separate file and the original file should be unaffected i.e. there should be no data in the original file unless you saved it manually. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing it and now it is fine!! I am having empty WB as I wanted! Thanks anyways! Topic closed =)

Comment: Just a warning, if the destination folder is syncing up to OneDrive, you need to get the local path ('.FullName' property) with a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive)

Comment: @Sgdva Good point. I use my own library for this kind of stuff. See [GetLocalPath](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools/blob/master/src/LibFileTools.bas#L720).

Answer (score 1):

```
fn = Replace(.FullName, ".xlsm", ".xlsx")



fn = Replace(.FullName, ".xlsm", date & ".xlsx")
```

Comment: Good point but I asked to take over the name of another wb that I am going to upload for data copy....check that example of me in the post.

Answer (score 1):

*What I just need (if possible) is to save my wb in the same name as that external wb that I am taking data from and adding date/time at the end*

You got the full path of your external wb in the variable `FilePath` so you can use that to save the workbook. You could save it like this (at the end of your sub `CopySheetFromClosedWorkbook2`):

```
Dim SaveName As String


SaveName = src.Path & "\" & Replace(Split(Filepath, "\")(UBound(Split(Filepath, "\"))), ".xlsm", Format(Date, "dd_mm_yyyy") & ".xlsx")


With ThisWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs SaveName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

Notice I'm using the object `src` to get the path where you want to save the new workbook, so you need to asign the line `SaveName = ....` anywhere before you do `src.Close`.

Comment: You mean to define SaveName = "location" C:\Users\MV\Desktop and also to feed it in "\"? 

and this src.Close False at the very end or?

Comment: @Mirza Yes I do