# Why is Excel vba adding quotation marks when I append to a file?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the first time I have tried to write a file from Excel using Open. I normally use FSO, but this code has to run on both Windows and MacOS.

```
Dim myFile As String
myFile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "CGATS.txt"
Open myFile For Append As #1
Write #1, "NUMBER_OF_FIELDS"
Write #1, "BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT"
Write #1, "SAMPLE_ID"
Write #1, "END_DATA_FORMAT"
Write #1, ""
Write #1, "NUMBER_OF_SETS" & vbTab & numRows
Write #1, "BEGIN_DATA" & vbTab & "LAB_L" & vbTab & "LAB_A" & vbTab & "LAB_B"
```

The code runs, but every line of output is surrounded by quotation marks

```
"NUMBER_OF_FIELDS"
"BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT"
"SAMPLE_ID"
"END_DATA_FORMAT"
""
"NUMBER_OF_SETS 52"
"BEGIN_DATA LAB_L   LAB_A   LAB_B"
```

Why is Excel doing this, and how do I get rid of the quotation marks?

Comment: I believe if you replace `Write` with command `Print` you will succeed

Comment: **Because it is supposed to**.  *Unlike the Print # statement, the Write # statement inserts commas between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written to the file. You don't have to put explicit delimiters in the list. Write # inserts a newline character, that is, a carriage return-linefeed (Chr(13) + Chr(10) ), after it has written the final character in outputlist to the file.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement

Comment: And it's the same format that Input# expects. *Data written with Write # is usually read from a file with Input #.*

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that stand out about your code.

1. First of all, you are just using `filenumber:=#1`, this will throw an error if this `filenumber` already happens to be in use. Better is to use the [`FreeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) function to find a free file number.
2. Also you are not currently using a [`close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/close-statement) statement. This is exactly a reason why the potential error mentioned in 1. might appear.
3. I assume, you want to base the file path of the created file on the workbook in which this macro is contained. Therefore, you shouldn't use `Application.ActiveWorkbook` to refer to this but rather, `Application.ThisWorkbook`, specifying `Application` is unnecessary, so you can instead just write `ThisWorkbook` to refer to, well, this workbook.
4. Since you are explicitly stating that your code should work on MacOS, you can't just use `"\"` as your path separator. Instead of that, use `Application.PathSeparator`.
5. And lastly, your actual question has of course already been answered in the comments by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel) and [@Lundt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19564057/lundt). To avoid adding quotation marks around every line, just use [`Print`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/printstatement) instead of [`Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/writestatement).

The fully refactored code might look something like this:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim fileFullName As String
    fileFullName = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "CGATS.txt"
    
    Dim fn As Long
    fn = FreeFile()
    
    Open fileFullName For Append As #fn
        Print #fn, "NUMBER_OF_FIELDS"
        Print #fn, "BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT"
        Print #fn, "SAMPLE_ID"
        Print #fn, "END_DATA_FORMAT"
        Print #fn, ""
        Print #fn, "NUMBER_OF_SETS" & vbTab & numRows
        Print #fn, "BEGIN_DATA" & vbTab & "LAB_L" & vbTab & "LAB_A" & vbTab & "LAB_B"
    Close #fn
End Sub
```

**Note:**

If your Workbook is located in a synced SharePoint or OneDrive folder, this code will still fail because `ThisWorkbook.Path` will then return the OneDrive Url, which the `open` statement can not deal with. In that case you have to copy the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457) and convert the path using the function by using `GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.path)`

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot from your answer.