# URL path for Folder (Using Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, url, sharepoint

In this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/url-path-for-folder-excel-vba/3aee38da-46af-4152-aa0c-55b7ecff2e4f

Have an answer that show how to get the URL.  I need to do this using VBA code.

Does someone can help me to get the URL path folder using VBA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive) - look for the **short solution** - otherwise the **Universal solution**

Comment: Actually in this page i see something tha helps me.
I use Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Thank for the Help