# How to retrieve local file paths in Excel 365 using VBA SendKeys?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive, vba7

I have one Excel workbook thats is sync local and online, if a open with onedrive running my excel reconize this workbook how online file, the excel 365 has a option (file>information>copy local path) if a file is also save local.

`SendKeys "%ail~"`  'this line get the text, end send to clipboard, works one time, but now nothing is send.

Sorry my english.

```
Sub TestPath()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim LocalString         As DataObject
    Dim CamLocalComplete    As String 'path file + name file
    Dim WorkBookName        As String 'name file
    Dim CamLocal            As String 'must be only local path file
    Set LocalString = New DataObject
    
    WorkBookName = ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set wb = Workbooks(WorkBookName)
    wb.Activate
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    'File > Informations > Copy local path
    SendKeys "%ail~"  'this line get the text send to clipboard, works one time, but now
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    'Back plan
    SendKeys "{ESC}"
    'Get cliboard text
    LocalString.GetFromClipboard
    CamLocalComplete = LocalString.GetText
    CamLocal = Left(CamLocalComplete, InStrRev(CamLocalComplete, "\") - 1)
    Range("E26").Value = CamLocal
End Sub
```

Comment: IMHO this is the wrong approach to get the local file name especially as Sendkeys is not reliable. Please have look [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools) for another approach

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive/73577057#73577057)

Comment: This approach is actually possible but not recommended. If you still want to try it out, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75751584/12287457), where this approach is discussed in detail. If you just want the best solution, follow the link to the accepted answer in the comment by @Storax.

Comment: Hi guys the post @Storax work for me https://stackoverflow.com/users/saves/5457834 thanks