# Excel VBA: How to set Worksheets object as a sheet from a file in onedrive?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

my code heavily relies of the fact that:

```
dim dataSource as Worksheet
```

is set as a sheet in another workbook as Im calling on it many times throughout my code. it works fine as long as that other workbook (sourcefile) is local. but now i need it to be relocated to one drive and i cannot find a way for this to work with onedrive files

at first i created my code to call on a local file using this method;

```
Dim dataSource As Worksheet
Set dataSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users...\\BMS Monitoring Data Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
```

and as long as the source file was local the code worked. then I had to relocate the source file to a one drive so I just replaced the URL with the new file location only in onedrive. and I mean that i navigated to the file with windows browser and copied the url. but that did not work. it said that the file cannot be located

I tried recoding the macro of how Im opening the file by going file/open/open from one drive... and the macro recorded this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=  "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/EnerzUAB/Shared%20Documents/.../BMS%20Monitoring%20Data%20Export.xlsx"
```

so I just copied that for this:

```
Dim dataSource As Worksheet
Set dataSource = Workbooks.Open Filename:= "https://company name.sharepoint.com/sites/EnerzUAB/Shared%20Documents/.../BMS%20Monitoring%20Data%20Export.xlsx"
```

and this gives an error : "Syntax error"

so I added parenthesis and .Sheets() at the end:

```
Dim dataSource As Worksheet
Set dataSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:= \_        "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/EnerzUAB/Shared%20Documents/.../BMS%20Monitoring%20Data%20Export.xlsx%22).Sheets(%22Sheet1")
```

now it just says that it cannot locate the file. does anyone know what is the problem here?

Comment: That last line doesn't look right at all. I suspect: `Set dataSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/EnerzUAB/Shared%20Documents/.../BMS%20Monitoring%20Data%20Export.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")` is what you need but with the full actual path, not those dots

Comment: See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/11318818)