# Understanding [Errno13] permission denied when trying to access local copies of sharepoint Excel files via Python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

I'm struggling to figure out what/why is causing periodic permission-denied errors when trying to work with local SharePoint files. This is just one example of some of my code, which essentially uses Excel as my team's front end for uploading to a database.

VBA code will call Python scripts that rely on `openpyxl` and `xlwings` to extract data from the Excel file and output data back to it. There is one template that will get saved by different members of the team, so the file location and file name will always be different.

Sometimes, the code runs without problems. Other times, I'll get the permission error. If the file is closed, it always runs. I thought it could have to do with syncing, but if the file is giving me the error, even if I pause OneDrive syncing, I'll still get the same error. Usually requires closing and reopening. I've also incorporated [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/10007302) into VBA, which will pull the local name and not the SharePoint address.

What am I missing and is there a more elegant solution that would be more reliable once rolled out to the rest of my team?

Here is one example of the Python code that may need to access the file.

```
def data_frame_from_xlsx_range(xlsx_file, range_name, date_columns=None):
    """ Get a single rectangular region from the specified file.
    range_name can be a standard Excel reference ('Sheet1!A2:B7') or
    refer to a named region ('my_cells')."""
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file, data_only=True, read_only=True)
    if '!' in range_name:
        # passed a worksheet!cell reference
        ws_name, reg = range_name.split('!')
        if ws_name.startswith("'") and ws_name.endswith("'"):
            # optionally strip single quotes around sheet name
            ws_name = ws_name[1:-1]
        region = wb[ws_name][reg]
    else:

        # passed a named range; find the cells in the workbook
    full_range = wb.get_named_range(range_name)
    if full_range is None:
        raise ValueError(
            'Range "{}" not found in workbook "{}".'.format(range_name, xlsx_file)
        )
    # convert to list (openpyxl 2.3 returns a list but 2.4+ returns a generator)
    destinations = list(full_range.destinations)

    if len(destinations) > 1:
        raise ValueError(
            'Range "{}" in workbook "{}" contains more than one region.'
            .format(range_name, xlsx_file)
        )
    ws, reg = destinations[0]
    # convert to worksheet object (openpyxl 2.3 returns a worksheet object
    # but 2.4+ returns the name of a worksheet)
    if isinstance(ws, str):
        ws = wb[ws]
    region = ws[reg]
# catch a single-cell range (untested):
# if not isinstance(region, 'tuple'): df = pd.DataFrame(region.value)
df = pd.DataFrame([cell.value for cell in row] for row in region)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = [col.replace(' ','_') for col in df.columns]
# drop any empty rows at the end of the data
df.dropna(thresh=1, inplace=True)
last_row_with_data = df[df.notna().any(axis=1)].index[-1]
df.drop(index=df.index[last_row_with_data + 1:], inplace=True)

def custom_date_parser(val):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(val, origin='1899-12-30', unit='D')
    except:
        return val

if date_columns:
    for col in date_columns:
        if col in df.columns:
            df[col] = df[col].apply(custom_date_parser)

return df
```

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\db_execution.py", line 185, in <module>
    match_names_to_db(fileloc, user, host, db )
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\db_execution.py", line 50, in match_names_to_db
    tracker_names = data_frame_from_xlsx_range(fileloc, 'tracker_names_to_match')
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\sqlupdate.py", line 15, in data_frame_from_xlsx_range
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xlsx_file, data_only=True, read_only=True)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\waly\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\waly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\zipfile.py", line 1248, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\waly\\OneDrive -  Global\\Documents\\National Corporation/Tracker Template_l_Group.xlsm'
```

Comment: Please update the question and include the full error traceback message.

Comment: @JohnGordon Done.

Comment: Not sure if this added context will help. Currently stuck in an access denied. I quite OneDrive completely and it still is giving me the same error. Quit my Python interpreter and still get it. Trying to narrow down potential causes

Comment: Have u tried a ohter location as a one Drive directory?

Comment: yes, same issues in other shared folders

Comment: Do you use a VPN to access your shared drives?