# Save email attachment to SharePoint/OneDrive

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using
[Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive).

Suddenly I can't save an email attachment to a folder in OneDrive anymore.

The code gets the file path but can't save, giving me an error.

```vb
For Each i In callfol.Items
    If i.Class = olMail Then
        Set mi = i
        If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 And Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") Then
            For Each at In mi.Attachments
                '------------,------------
                at.SaveAsFile (fPat & "/Outlookdata/calls mtd/" & Date & "." & FSO.GetExtensionName(fPat & "/Outlookdata/calls mtd/" & at.fileName))
            Next at
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77514627/edit) the question. [mcve]. Try to create code for Outlook only, to eliminate Excel as a factor if possible.

Comment: Thanks, i did my best and formatted it like you said!

Comment: Although nothing has changed, and the code has been working for months or years even.
But suddenly it cant save the file in onedrive.

Comment: Start the [mcve] with `Option Explicit` end with `End Sub`. Try it before posting. State the error message.

Comment: BTW, using parenthesis around arguments in simple function calls without used return value as in `at.SaveAsFile ( fPat ... ))` can be very misleading and might not do what you think it does.

Comment: It has been working fine, but sure my code isent the best,.
this is the path i get and that usually have benn working.
My path becomes this:
https://XXXXX-my.sharepoint.com/personal/XXXXXX_com/Documents/VBA cloud/VBA\Outlookdata\calls mtd\23-11-20.png

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `Attachment.SaveAsFile` only allows to save to a file drive. You cannot save to an `http`/`https` location (if that is what `fPat` points to, one cannot tell from your post).

Secondly, do not use `Date` (as least without formatting it in a predictable manner) as part of the file name since it can include characters invalid in file names, such as `"/"`, `":"`, etc..

Comment: I use the workaround from the link to a function in my first post, it has been working fine.

Comment: My path becomes this:
https://XXXXX-my.sharepoint.com/personal/XXXXXX_com/Documents/VBA cloud/VBA\Outlookdata\calls mtd\23-11-20.png
And has been working until yesterday.

Comment: I am surprised it ever worked - `SaveAsFile` has never supported HTTP paths. It only works with file system. You probably previously worked with a local file folder mapped to OneDrive, which then later got synchronized with the Cloud drive,

Comment: No the code has been exactly the same, it has been saving to the "cloud" and has been working, thats whats so strange.
I guess it has been working due to the function i used that i link to in my first post right? thats whats that function is for?
Humm, no wait, maybe the function dosent work anymore, the function maybe changed the http path to something vba could use?
But what has changed..

Comment: Ahhh, it seems to be something wrong with the function. it suppose to change to a local path that can be used. 
'This Function will convert a OneDrive/SharePoint Url path, e.g. Url containing
'https://d.docs.live.net/; .sharepoint.com/sites; my.sharepoint.com/personal/...
'to the locally synchronized path on your current pc or mac, e.g. a path like
'C:\users\username\OneDrive\ on Windows; or /Users/username/OneDrive/ on MacOS,
'if you have the remote directory locally synchronized with the OneDrive app.

Comment: But it dosent änymore, so something changed and the function from this site dosent work suddenly and just gives me the http path.

Ive tried it like this:
'USAGE EXAMPLES:
'Excel:
Private Sub TestGetLocalPathExcel()
    Debug.Print GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    Debug.Print GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.path)
End Sub

Comment: ok, dimitry, ill try to see why it stopped giving me a real file path and started to give me an url. Its so strange. Ill try to get in contact with the creator of the Function.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the code for the function when i realized the issue, the creator of the code helped me.
Thank you all who tried to help me.
The latest code were here.
https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d