# Outlook File Attachment using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm encountering an issue with my VBA code for sending Outlook emails with attachments. The code is intended to generate a file path and attach the file to an Outlook email. However, I'm consistently getting an error stating that the file doesn't exist or has a bad file or path name.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim OutlookMail2 As Object
    Dim WordDocument As Document
    Dim FilePath1 As String
    Dim FilePath2 As String
    Dim emailBody As String
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim userResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    ' Create an instance of Outlook
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set OutlookMail2 = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Randomize
    
    Dim random4DigitNumber As String
    random4DigitNumber = Format(Int((9999 * Rnd) + 100), "0000")
    
    Dim ticketNumber As String
    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(TextBox1.Value, " ")
        ' Check if there's at least one part
    If UBound(parts) >= 0 Then
        ' Get the first value
        
        ticketNumber = Trim(parts(0))
        
        ' Display the first value
        MsgBox "First Value: " & ticketNumber
    Else
        MsgBox "No parts found in the string."
    End If
    
    ' Extract numeric part from ticketNumber
Dim numericPart As String
numericPart = VBA.Strings.Mid(ticketNumber, InStr(ticketNumber, "_") + 1)

' Use only the numeric part
ticketNumber = Trim(numericPart)
    'ticketNumber = Trim(TextBox1.Value.Split("(")) ' Trim leading and trailing spaces
 
   ' Set the file path for the exported document
FilePath1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\PAP_" & ticketNumber & "_" & random4DigitNumber & ".docm"
FilePath2 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\PAP_" & ticketNumber & "_" & random4DigitNumber & ".pdf"

    
    If ticketNumber = "" Then
        MsgBox "No value provided. Execution halted.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub ' Exit the code
    End If
    
    userInput = InputBox("If you want to add something in the email body", "Email Body")
    
    emailBody = "Hello Team,<br><br>" & _
                 "Please find attached PAP for the A+ ticket (<b>" & ticketNumber & "</b>).<br>" & _
                 userInput & "<br><br>Regards,<br>" & Application.UserName
    
    userResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send the file?", vbOKCancel)
    
    If userResponse <> vbOK Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
        ' Save the active document with a new name
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath1, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled

MsgBox Dir(FilePath1)
    
    ' Configure the email
    With OutlookMail
        .To = "xyz.abc.com"
        .Cc = "xyz.gef.com"
        .Subject = "Preventive Action Plan - " & ticketNumber
        .HTMLBody = emailBody
        .Attachments.Add FilePath1
        ' Display the email for the user to review (optional)
        .Display
        
        ' Send the email
        '.Send
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

I can confirm that the file path is correctly generated and the file exists at that location. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: are you using One Drive?

Comment: Its likely you have an extraneous space, missed \, or doube \ somewhere in your file path.

Comment: @freeflow I have been very careful about that. Using Trim() everywhere, so I don't leave an extra space anywhere. This is the output of "FilePath1" : "C:\Users\<user-id>\Documents\PAP_20202020_2345.docm"

Comment: @Ike No, I am not using OneDrive

Comment: Just to be on the safe side (as the documents folder might get synchronize) try Solution 2 from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/16578424 - and then `debug.print GetLocalPath("C:\Users\<user-id>\Documents\PAP_20202020_2345.docm")`

Comment: You can also check the length of ticketNumber  to make sure it doesn't have a non visible control character at the end of it.

Comment: Is this a corporate set up or your personal PC - because if it is corporate it's likely that the location you have shared *is* a OneDrive path. In which case you will need to use the URL of the file

Comment: @Ike, I've verified that the file is stored in OneDrive. I've implemented the solution you provided, and while it works on certain occasions, there are instances where it doesn't. I'm having difficulty understanding the reasons behind this inconsistency.

Comment: The goal is to attach the active document to an Outlook email triggered by a button click. To customize the file name, I save a copy in a separate location and use that path for the attachment.

However, I've encountered a 'Permission Denied' access issue when attempting to create a copy of the active document

Comment: Check out https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools --> there you find updated code to retrieve a onedrive path.

Comment: @Ike Your provided solution did the trick! Thank you so much. I genuinely appreciate it. Also, a big thanks to others who dedicated their time to address the issue.