# ThisWorkbook.Path returning Path not found

Tags: excel, vba

Currently trying to use relative paths in this macro so I can send it out to other people I work with.  The workbook has been saved but I am getting the error "Path not Found".

```
Sub NewestFileWorking()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fol As Object
Dim fil As Object
Dim temp As Date

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path)

Dim newest As Date
Dim newestFile As String
For Each fil In fol.Files
    temp = fil.DateLastModified
    If (newest = #12:00:00 AM#) Or (temp > newest) Then
        newest = temp
        newestFile = fil.Path
    End If
Next fil
MsgBox "Newest File: " & newestFile & " (" & newest & ")"
Workbooks.Open newestFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saving the file on OneDrive? Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/16578424