# VBA for moving files from one SharePoint folder to another

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I created a macro in Excel to move files from one folder to another.  I did so on my local machine and did not consider that the macro would be impacted for other users that are using Remote Desktop to access the same Excel.  I realized that the path I was using was for OneDrive and would need amended to work with SharePoint instead. I have tried every combination I can find on the net and am finally asking the experts.

Thank you in advance (My code below)

```
Sub MoveFiles()

'Move previous days' files to folder "PreviousRateSheets"

Dim SourceFolderPath As String
Dim DestinationFolderPath As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim File As Object
Dim FileName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'ORIGINAL CODE - Worked on my local machine but not on other users' machines
'sourceFolderPath = "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet"
'destinationFolderPath = "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\PreviousRateSheets"

'SECOND ATTEMP USING "Environ("OneDrive")" - Didn't work on either my machine nor my RDP
'sourceFolderPath = Environ("OneDrive") & "\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet\"
'destinationFolderPath = Environ("OneDrive") & "\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\PreviousRateSheets"

'This Path structure works elsewhere in another script to save the requisite files to SharePoint
SourceFolderPath = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/TodayRateSheet/"
DestinationFolderPath = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/PreviousRateSheet/"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.Getfolder(SourceFolderPath) 'This is the point the error 76 "Path not Found" fires

For Each File In SourceFolder.Files
    FileName = File.Name
    sourceFilePath = File.Path
    destinationFilePath = DestinationFolderPath & "/" & FileName
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=sourceFilePath, Destination:=destinationFilePath
Next

'Don't need set file to nothing because it is initialized in for each loop
'and after this loop is automatically set to Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel's fullname property with OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environ ("USERPROFILE")` to replace `C:\Users\yourusername`

So instead of:

```
sourceFolderPath = "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet"
destinationFolderPath = "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\PreviousRateSheets"
```

Try:

```
sourceFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet"
destinationFolderPath = Environ ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\PreviousRateSheets"
```

Note that users do have the ability to choose a different location for their OneDrive root folder, and they might sync to the SharePoint site at different folder levels - either of these would need further changes to the paths.

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734706/excels-fullname-property-with-onedrive/73577057#73577057) and [this](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools) helpful.

Comment: I am still getting an error (no. 76 - Path Not Found) at the line "Set SourceFolder = FSO.Getfolder(SourceFolderPath)"

Comment: What do you get from just the single line `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet"` using `debug.print` or in the immediate window? Is it the same as `"C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX, Inc\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX\TodayRateSheet"`

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt should have worked.

I use this code to find a file in a parent folder from where the Excel file is located.
I know the file is there but the name could change slightly, there could be more than one file that are like it, but this file is mine.

First you need Microsoft scripting runtime reference added.

```
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim f As File
    Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

    ' here I get the https:// sharepoint path and make the / to \
    ' the InStrRev and Left moves up one level in the folder structure
    pth = Replace(Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "/")), "/", "\") 
    ' I just need the part that is after onedrive in the path
    pth = Mid(pth, InStr(pth, "Lokala uppgifter"), 9999)
    
    Debug.Print pth
    ' here I merge the OneDrive and pth from above to get the correct path and loop to find the file name.
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(Environ("OneDrive") & "\" & pth) 
    For Each f In folder.Files
        If f Like "*Mottagningkontroll*" Then
            Debug.Print f
        End If
    Next f
```

I realize this is not a copy paste answer for you but perhaps there are parts that you can use.