Dir function not working properly with SharePoint folders
I have a macro that reads the files within a folder that the user indicates in a prompt box. It works fine with mapped folders, but my company is transitioning from those mapped folders to SharePoint and I'm testing if everything is ok.
However, when I run the macro and I get the prompt box, I insert the folder path in SharePoint and the macro stops, redirecting to the debug window. The relevant code is as follows:

Option Explicit

Sub AnaliseDados()

    ' Desativa a atualização do ecrã
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Definição de variáveis a serem usadas
    Dim FicAnaDad As Workbook           ' Ficheiro de análise de outputs
    Dim Fol As Worksheet                ' Folhas de dados a serem analisadas
    Dim FolBdPro As Worksheet           ' Folha da base de dados de produto
    Dim FolBdLoc As Worksheet           ' Folha da base de dados de locais
    Dim FolBdMov As Worksheet           ' Folha da base de dados de movimentos
    Dim FolBdBle As Worksheet           ' Folha de base de dados de blendings
    Dim CamDir As String                ' Caminho para o diretório com ficheiros a analisar
    Dim AnaDir As String                ' Variável de análise de diretórios
    Dim FolRep As Worksheet             ' Folha de extended report a ser analisada
    Dim DicNomPro As Variant            ' Dicionário de nome de produtos e códigos
    Dim DicDesPro As Variant            ' Dicionário de descrição de produtos e códigos
    Dim DicLoc As Variant               ' Dicionário de locais e códigos
    Dim NomFic As String                ' Nome do ficheiro a ser gravado
    
    ' Definição dos ficheiros a serem usados
    Set FicAnaDad = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    
    ' Limpa todos as selecções de filtros
    For Each Fol In FicAnaDad.Worksheets
        Call LimpaFiltros(Fol)
    Next
    
    ' Definição das folhas a serem usadas
    Set FolBdPro = FicAnaDad.Worksheets("BD produtos")
    Set FolBdLoc = FicAnaDad.Worksheets("BD locais")
    Set FolBdMov = FicAnaDad.Worksheets("BD movimentos")
    Set FolBdBle = FicAnaDad.Worksheets("BD Blendings")
    
    ' Definição dos dicionários a serem usados
    Set DicNomPro = CriarDicionario(FolBdPro, 2)
    Set DicDesPro = CriarDicionario(FolBdPro, 3)
    Set DicLoc = CriarDicionario(FolBdLoc, 2)
    
    ' Pergunta ao utilizador qual o diretório onde se encontram os extended reports a serem analisados
    CamDir = EscolherDiretorio
    
    ' Analisa todos os ficheiros de extendend report na pasta definida
   AnaDir = Dir(CamDir & "/*ExtendedRpts*")
    Do While Len(AnaDir) > 0
        
        ' Definição do ficheiro de extended report a ser analisado
        Set FolRep = Workbooks.Open(CamDir & "\" & AnaDir).Worksheets(1)
        
        ' Copia os dados relevantes de movimentos para a BD de movimentos
        Call DadosMovimentos(FolBdMov, FolBdBle, FolRep, DicNomPro, DicDesPro, DicLoc)
        
        ' Copia os dados relevantes de blendings para a folha BD de blendings
        
        ' Grava o ficheiro de análise atualizado
        NomFic = Split(AnaDir, ".")(0)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Análise outputs-" & NomFic & ".xlsm"
        
        ' Altera o ficheiro de extended report a ser analisado
        AnaDir = Dir
    Loop
    
    ' Fecha a folha de análise de dados
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    ' Ativa a atualização do ecrã
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


Please ignore comments in Portuguese. Essentially the 'CamDir = EscolherDiretorio' row calls the 'EscolherDiretorio' function that opens a dialogue box and where I insert the folder path I get from SharePoint. In the debugging window I can see that 'CamDir' assumes the folder path, it's ok. However the row with
AnaDir = Dir(CamDir & "/*ExtendedRpts*")
That is supposed to create a file path for all the files within the indicated folder ending in 'ExtendedRpts' doesn't work properly. In the original code the / bar before *ExtendedRpts was a \ bar. Just changed because all the bars in the SharePoint path are /.
Another finding is that the SharePoint path appears to be dynamic. If I get it in different moments the last characters vary. Here's 3 examples:
https://galp.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/EM-PortfolioOptimization/Shared%20Documents/Teste%20de%20tenders/537%20-%20Torrijos%20-%20Consigna%C3%A7%C3%A3o/3.%20Resultados?csf=1&web=1&e=t1Zm8g
https://galp.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/EM-PortfolioOptimization/Shared%20Documents/Teste%20de%20tenders/537%20-%20Torrijos%20-%20Consigna%C3%A7%C3%A3o/3.%20Resultados?csf=1&web=1&e=1ViCo5
https://galp.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/EM-PortfolioOptimization/Shared%20Documents/Teste%20de%20tenders/537%20-%20Torrijos%20-%20Consigna%C3%A7%C3%A3o/3.%20Resultados?csf=1&web=1&e=zF0XSU
I'm wondering if at the time the macro reads the folder path and tries to access it the path has already changed...
Could you help with some guidance, please?
As explained above I have switched a \ bar to / bar in the code in order to comply with SharePoint path style, but it still doesn't work.
The solutions proposed around don't fit my needs, as they refer to OneDrive by using new libraries or functions. I just want to tell my macro the path of a folder where the files I need to read are saved. Apparently SharePoint is changing the last characters of the path any time I get the link of the folder of interest (by clicking the 3 dots at the righ side and copying link).

This question is similar to: Excel's fullname property with OneDrive. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Look at this brilliant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/16578424

Note most suggestions you'll find here are for SharePoint folders which have been synchronized to your local PC.  If that's not the case then it gets more difficult.  Using VBA to work with SP isn't simple, so you're going to need to make some significant changes to your code.

Here is an example of how you can use SQL via ADO to query a SharePoint library for specific file types.
It doesn't rely on the library or folder being synced to the local PC, but you do need to provide the path to the site and the library GUID, which you can get from the browser URL when viewing the Library settings:
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Site33/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7Babcdec-9f6c-56hg-82f9-1d9682e46881%7D
The %7B and %7D represent { and } so the guid you need is (in this example):
{abcdec-9f6c-56hg-82f9-1d9682e46881}
Sub ListSPLibraryFiles()
    '## Add a VBA project reference to the ADO object library ##
    Const SERVERUrl As String = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Site33"
    Const ListName As String = "{abcdec-9f6c-56hg-82f9-1d9682e46881}" 'List/Library *GUID*
    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql As String, objWksheet As Worksheet, el, cerr
    
    
    With Conn
        'IMEX  0=write   1=read  2=RWD      ";
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                                "DATABASE=" & SERVERUrl & ";" & _
                                 "List=" & ListName & ";"
        .Open
    End With
    
    'query all library records for (eg) xls* docs
    sql = "SELECT [Name],[Path],[Content Type], [File Type] " & _
          " FROM [" & ListName & "] where [Content Type]='Document' and [File Type] like 'xls%'"
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, Conn, adOpenStatic
    
    PutToSheet rs, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results") 'display the results
    
    rs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Sub

'load field names and data from `rs` to worksheet `ws`
Sub PutToSheet(rs As ADODB.Recordset, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim f As ADODB.Field, i As Long, rw As Range, v
    With ws
        .Cells.Clear 'clear any previous data
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            For Each f In rs.Fields
                ws.Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value = f.Name
                i = i + 1
            Next f
            Set rw = ws.Rows(2)
            Do While Not rs.EOF
                For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                    Set f = rs.Fields(i)
                    v = f.Value
                    'the "Name" filed has some extra info after `#` - trim that off
                    Select Case f.Name
                        Case "Name": v = "'" & Split(v, "#")(0)
                    End Select
                    rw.Cells(i + 1).Value = v
                Next i
                Set rw = rw.Offset(1)
                rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub

